# Remove EventListener with a bind function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm listening to a `deviceorientationabsolute` event like this (on `ngOnInit`):

```
 this.deviceOrientationEvent = this.onDeviceOrientation.bind(this);
 window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", this.deviceOrientationEvent);
```

I want to stop listening to that event on `ngOnDestroy`. I tried this:

```
window.removeEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", this.deviceOrientationEvent);
```

But I can still see in the console that it's listening to the event.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling through `window.addEventListener` method you can handle it using `@HostListener` as below

```
@HostListener('window:deviceorientationabsolute', ['$event'])
deviceOrientationAbsoluteEvent(event) { ... }
```

It will be automatically removed when component will be destroyed

Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41032388/9380944 answer for more details.