# Iterate getEventListeners() return object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am searching for a way to iterate the object `getEventListeners(obj)` returns.
This way, I wouldn't need specific code to iterate event listener types, or to check if they exist on the checked element.

My goal is to remove some event listeners from an element. For example remove all mouse related ones, and keep the others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`getEventListeners()` will return simple JS object, you can iterate objects like this:

```
var listeners = window.getEventListeners(document.body);
Object.keys(listeners).forEach(event => {
    console.log(event, listeners[event]);
});
```

But looks like that `getEventListeners` method is available only in chrome, and only by manual entry in DevTools.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't realize this is chrome specific :( But this is the answer to the question, so thank you

Comment: getEventListeners is not a javascript function (it only works on the dev tools command line)

Comment: is there any alternative function of getEventListeners  ?  which I can use my js file

Comment: @Arif The alternative is to keep track of the event listeners you attach yourself in an array or object. Of course, this will not track event listeners added by 3rd party code. There is no other alternative.

Answer (score 23):

`getEventListeners(obj)` is only a [Google Chrome specific Command Line Tool feature](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#getEventListeners-function). This means that you can only use this feature inside Chrome Dev Tools when manually typing into the console. You cannot use this method in your actual JavaScript source code.

If you want to achieve what you described, AFAIK you have to keep track of your listeners manually. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469881/remove-all-event-listeners-of-specific-type) for further instructions.

Comment: the link to Chrome Specific Tools is broken, it's https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#getEventListeners-function and has a list of all tools.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is old, but there is a library that allows for the use of `.getEventListeners()` function outside of Chrome's Dev Tools

https://github.com/colxi/getEventListeners

```
let myEl = document.getElementById('someElementId');

// add some event listeners to the Element
myEl.addEventListener('click', e=> console.log('click!') );
myEl.addEventListener('click', e=> console.log('click 2!') );
myEl.addEventListener('mouseover', e=> console.log('mouse over!') );

// retrieve the listeners
console.log( myEl.getEventListeners() );
```

Might be of help to someone.