# How to copy Event Listener's attached anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to build a *Tampermonkey* user script that modifies the functionality of an event applied to an element.

Let's say the source website have this:

```
<div id="item_1">…</div>
```

And within the source website's Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("item_1").addeventlistener("click", function(){
    // Source website's lines of code for the function to be applied on click event occurrence.
}
```

I know that I can easily overwrite the event functionality by using:

```
document.getElementById("item_1").addeventlistener("click", function(){
    // My lines of code here
}
```

But what I'm looking for is to first copy the `anonymous function` that was previously passed-in to the `addEventListener` method. I want to copy it to a temporary variable so that I can retrieve the original Event Listener attached function back.

There's another question having an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411683/3503851) telling that copying functions of Event Listeners is impossible. I believe this may be possible somehow as I think that the passed-in anonymous function is stored within the heap with some reference. If I'm able to get that reference, I will be able to get a copy for the code to another variable.

I don't have access to edit the source's script. I know that I could have refactored the code to handle event population. Also, I know I can do some manipulation on the source's JavaScript, but I don't want to go this way as my user script code will get too complicated and if the source code was changed a little, my code will be broken easily. I want to easily copy the Event Listener function to a variable I have.

Comment: What about `getEventListeneres` before adding / overriding your implementation? (From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46974757/4062197)

Comment: You might want to override `addEventListener` to intercept the argument

Comment: @ymz Does Tampermonkey provide that function? It's not available natively in the DOM.