# How to ignore or stop old events bounded to a DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to ignore, remove, or stop all `keydown` events bounded to a DOM.

I have used the following code. but it just works in the console. I need to run it on the page and out of the console.

```
var events = getEventListeners(document);
var keydowns = events.keydown;

keydowns.forEach(element => {

    document.removeEventListener(element.type, element.listener);

});
```

> The problem is **getEventListeners()** function is **defined only in the console** and is **undefined on the page**.

Comment: `getEventListeners(obj)` is only a Google Chrome specific Command Line Tool feature https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974675/iterate-geteventlisteners-return-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate getEventListeners() return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974675/iterate-geteventlisteners-return-object)

Comment: Interesting article [List EVERY event that exists in the browser](https://www.perimeterx.com/tech-blog/2019/list-every-event-that-exists-in-the-browser/)

Comment: @Sascha I need an alternative way to gain events and remove them that working on the page.