# How to delete listener with anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using **MindFusion** library for Diagramming. For example, I have that listener:

```
diagram.addEventListener(Events.nodeCreating, function (sender, args) {

    diagram.removeEventListener(Events.nodeCreating, ????)

});
```

How can i remove it when my function is anonymous? It works when i will name it:

```
diagram.addEventListener(Events.nodeCreating, function tmp(sender, args) {

    diagram.removeEventListener(Events.nodeCreating, tmp)

});
```

but is there anyway to do it without forcing the name to that function? What should i put into "handler" parametr?

[image]

Comment: I don’t think you can if the handler is anonymous

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removeEventListener on anonymous functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950115/removeeventlistener-on-anonymous-functions-in-javascript)