# how is to remove the EventListener?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove the EventListener? Attached is a quick example of where it doesn't work. How should it be correct?

```
function test_function(a='', b='') {    
    console.log('test_function started. a='+a+', b='+b);    
}

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=>{   test_function('testa', 'testb');    });
document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", test_function );
```

Comment: You have attached an anonymous function to the event, not `test_function`.

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the anonymous function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950115/removeeventlistener-on-anonymous-functions-in-javascript

Comment: for further reference to the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener _"Given an event listener previously added by calling addEventListener(), you may eventually come to a point at which you need to remove it. Obviously, you need to specify the same type and listener parameters to removeEventListener()."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*test_function* is not the event listener function of the event handler.
it is
`()=>{   test_function('testa', 'testb')`
this whole anonymous function.

In this `document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", test_function );` you are passing reference of test_function to removeEventListener. but the actual function is `()=>{   test_function('testa', 'testb')`

In order to use removeEventListener, you can refactor code this way.

```
function test_function(a='', b='') {    
    console.log('test_function started. a='+a+', b='+b);    
}

const handleMouseMove = () => test_function('testa', 'testb');

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
```

checkout mdn documentation,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: And how can I add the event in a single line? That would be clearer in my case.

Comment: the point is that you need to pass the same event handler function reference for both addEventListener and removeEventListener. hope you understand!

Comment: @Frank_G, do you want to remove event listener after it gets executed once?

Comment: I want to add an event with dynamical parameters. And on other place I want to remove the event. If I could make setting and removing the event in one line of code each, that would be clearer.