# How to remove hashchange event listener based on flag condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the hashchange event listener based on the flag i have set as shown below;

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
   if (isPopupOpen){
    
       popup.classList.remove('active');
      
       popup.style.transform = 'translateY(25%)';
       popup.style.height = '75%';
        
       //popup.style.display = "none";
       isPopupOpen = false;
        
      document.head.appendChild(con);
      popcontainer.style.display = "none";
    } 

   // This did not remove the hashchange event listener;
    if (!isPopupOpen){
        window.removeEventListener("hashchange", this)
    }
  });
```

I have tried to remove the event listener when isPopupOpen flag is false but that did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removeEventListener on anonymous functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950115/removeeventlistener-on-anonymous-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: Another option would be to suppress the relevant handler execution by early return based on some flag(s).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove the listener by passing `this` to removeEventListener, but `this` in the context of the event listener function does not refer to the function itself.

```
if (!isPopupOpen){
  window.removeEventListener("hashchange", this)
}
```

There is a better way to do this.

Instead of creating and defining the function there, we could create the function with the conditions and then when we add the event listener, we can call the function.

So something like this

```
function handleHashChange(e) {
    if (isPopupOpen) {
        // Add the event listener
    } else {
        //If isPopupOpen flag is false remove the event listener
        window.removeEventListener("hashchange", handleHashChange);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("hashchange", handleHashChange);
```

Something like this should work well and let you remove the event listener.

Comment: I tried this but the app still listens to this event.