# How to removeEventListener that is addEventListener with anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, anonymous-function

```
function doSomethingWith(param)
{
    document.body.addEventListener(
        'scroll',
        function()
        {
            document.write(param);
        },
        false
    ); // An event that I want to remove later
}
setTimeout(
    function()
    {
        document.body.removeEventListener('scroll', HANDLER ,false);
            // What HANDLER should I specify to remove the anonymous handler above?
    },
    3000
);
doSomethingWith('Test. ');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can't. You have to use a named function or store the reference somehow.

```
var handler;

function doSomethingWith(param) {
    handler = function(){
        document.write(param);
    };  
    document.body.addEventListener('scroll', handler,false);
}
setTimeout(function() {
     document.body.removeEventListener('scroll', handler ,false);
}, 3000);
```

The best would be to do this in a structured way, so that you can identify different handlers and remove them. In the example above, you obviously could only remove the last handler.

**Update:**

You could create your own handler handler (:)) :

```
var Handler = (function(){
    var i = 1,
        listeners = {};

    return {
        addListener: function(element, event, handler, capture) {
            element.addEventListener(event, handler, capture);
            listeners[i] = {element: element, 
                             event: event, 
                             handler: handler, 
                             capture: capture};
            return i++;
        },
        removeListener: function(id) {
            if(id in listeners) {
                var h = listeners[id];
                h.element.removeEventListener(h.event, h.handler, h.capture);
                delete listeners[id];
            }
        }
    };
}());
```

Then you can use it with:

```
function doSomethingWith(param) {
    return Handler.addListener(document.body, 'scroll', function() {
        document.write(param);
    }, false);
}

var handler = doSomethingWith('Test. ');

setTimeout(function() {
     Handler.removeListener(handler);
}, 3000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/cSTe4/)

Comment: Could you explain what the structured way is? My English skill is not good enough to understand that... Thanks.

Comment: @Japboy: You're welcome :) I just noticed a slight mistake and fixed it.

Comment: Why would you wrap the addListener and removeListener?

Comment: @useless: Do you mean the self-invoking function? To keep `i` and `listeners` "private".

Comment: Can you update the functions so that it doesn't leak memory? Or at least state that it does?

Comment: @Bergi: Done. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Nice answer +1 but the code is old school with room for improvements, see my answer (which provides both JS and TypeScript solutions)

Answer (score 11):

You can't, you need a reference to the function:

```
function doSomethingWith(param) {
   var fn = function(){ document.write(param); };
   document.body.addEventListener('scroll', fn, false);
   setTimeout(function(){ document.body.removeEventListener('scroll', fn, false); }, 3000);
}
doSomethingWith('Test. ');
```

Comment: how do u pass event object?

Comment: @slier `var fn = function(event){ document.write(param); };`

Answer (score 7):

You could also do this like that:

```
const ownAddEventListener = (scope, type, handler, capture) => {
  scope.addEventListener(type, handler, capture);
  return () => {
    scope.removeEventListener(type, handler, capture);    
  }
}
```

Then you can remove the event listener like this:

```
// Add event listener
const disposer = ownAddEventListener(document.body, 'scroll', () => { 
  // do something
}, false);

// Remove event listener
disposer();
```

Comment: Is it possible to determine which events have been bound on the object like this?

Comment: You could just add some properties to the function, like the type, scope etc.
`const disposerFn = () => { scope.removeEventListener(type, handler, capture); }`
    `disposerFn.type = type;`
    `return disposerFn;`

Answer (score 4):

This significantly improves upon the top @FelixKling answer. Improvements are:

(1) Aligned with [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which refer to type, listener, useCapture

(2) Removes old school IIFE and adopts a class based approach

(3) Added `addEventListenerById` method which supports using your own custom ID (and avoids the need to retrieve ID from return value)

(4) `removeEventListener` method returns ID of removed listener or null

(5) Added `length` method to return the number of active listeners

(6) Added SO code snippet (to prove it works)

Code follows:

```js
class Listeners {

  #listeners = {} // # in a JS class signifies private 
  #idx = 1

  // add event listener, returns integer ID of new listener
  addEventListener(element, type, listener, useCapture = false) {
    this.#privateAddEventListener(element, this.#idx, type, listener, useCapture)
    return this.#idx++
  }
  
  // add event listener with custom ID (avoids need to retrieve return ID since you are providing it yourself)
  addEventListenerById(element, id, type, listener, useCapture = false) {
    this.#privateAddEventListener(element, id, type, listener, useCapture)
    return id
  }

  #privateAddEventListener(element, id, type, listener, useCapture) {
    if (this.#listeners[id]) throw Error(`A listener with id ${id} already exists`)
    element.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)
    this.#listeners[id] = {element, type, listener, useCapture}
  }

  // remove event listener with given ID, returns ID of removed listener or null (if listener with given ID does not exist)
  removeEventListener(id) {
    const listen = this.#listeners[id]
    if (listen) {
      listen.element.removeEventListener(listen.type, listen.listener, listen.useCapture)
      delete this.#listeners[id]
    }
    return !!listen ? id : null
  }

  // returns number of events listeners
  length() {
    return Object.keys(this.#listeners).length
  }
}

// For demo purposes only, a button to which the click listeners will be attached
const testBtn = document.querySelector('.test-button')

// Usage
const listeners = new Listeners() // in a modular environment ... export const listeners = new Listeners()

const listener1 = listeners.addEventListener(testBtn, 'click', e => console.log('hello from click listener #1', e.offsetX, e.offsetY))
const listener2 = listeners.addEventListener(testBtn, 'click', e => console.log('hello from click listener #2', e.offsetX, e.offsetY))
listeners.addEventListenerById(testBtn, 'listener-id', 'click', e => console.log('hello from click listener #listener-id', e.offsetX, e.offsetY))

// Click function for the 3 remove listener buttons (not for the testBtn to which the listeners are attached)
const onRemoveClick = (id) => {
  const removed = listeners.removeEventListener(id)
  if (removed == null) {
    console.log(`cannot remove listener #${id} (does not exist)`)
  } else {
    console.log(`ID of removed listener #${removed}`)
  }
  const listenersCount = listeners.length()
  console.log(`there are ${listenersCount} listeners still listening`)
}
```

```css
.test-button {
  width: 35%;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.remove-listener-button {
  width: 15%;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button class="test-button">click to prove multiple listeners are listening to my click</button>

<button class="remove-listener-button" onclick="onRemoveClick(1)">remove listener #1</button>
<button class="remove-listener-button" onclick="onRemoveClick(2)">remove listener #2</button>
<button class="remove-listener-button" onclick="onRemoveClick('listener-id')">remove #listener-id</button>
```

**FOR TYPESCRIPT LOVERS**

Here's the same in TypeScript with some enhancements to the above JS version:

(1) `removeEventListener` method returns details of the removed listener (including ID) as opposed to only the ID of the removed listener

(2) Added `ids` method which returns the ids of all active listeners

(3) Added 3 methods `addEventListeners` `addEventListenersByIds` `removeEventListeners` which allow you to add / remove multiple listeners in one call (see usage example below)

(4) Added `removeAllEventListeners` and `destroy` methods for cleanup (essentially these 2 are the same but the latter does not return a value)

Here's the TypeScript code (just copy and paste into a new .ts file):

```
interface IInternalListener {
  element: HTMLElement
  id: string
  type: string
  listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject
  useCapture: boolean
}

export interface IListener extends Omit<IInternalListener, 'id'> {
  id: string | number
}

class Listeners {

  #listeners: { [key: string]: IInternalListener } = {}
  #idx = 1 // # in a JS class signifies private

  // add event listener, returns integer ID of new listener
  addEventListener(element: HTMLElement, type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture = false): number {
    this.#privateAddEventListener(element, this.#idx.toString(), type, listener, useCapture)
    return this.#idx++
  }

  addEventListeners(element: HTMLElement, types: string[], listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture = false): number[] {
    const returnIds: number[] = []
    types.forEach((type: string) => {
      const returnId: number = this.addEventListener(element, type, listener, useCapture)
      returnIds.push(returnId)
    })
    return returnIds
  }

  // add event listener with custom ID (avoids need to retrieve return ID since you are providing it yourself)
  addEventListenerById(element: HTMLElement, id: string | number, type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture = false): string | number { // eslint-disable-line max-len
    return this.#privateAddEventListener(element, id.toString(), type, listener, useCapture)
  }

  addEventListenersByIds(element: HTMLElement, ids: Array<string | number>, types: string[], listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture = false): Array<string | number> { // eslint-disable-line max-len
    const returnIds: Array<string | number> = []
    if (ids.length !== types.length) throw Error(`Cannot add ${types.length} event listeners using ${ids.length} ids - ids and types must be of equal length`)
    types.forEach((type: string, idx: number) => {
      const id: string | number = ids[idx]
      const returnId: string | number = this.addEventListenerById(element, id, type, listener, useCapture)
      returnIds.push(returnId)
    })
    return returnIds
  }

  // remove event listener with given ID, returns removed listener or null (if listener with given ID does not exist)
  removeEventListener(id: string | number): IListener | null {
    const strId: string = id.toString()
    const internalListener: IInternalListener = this.#listeners[strId]
    if (internalListener) {
      internalListener.element.removeEventListener(internalListener.type, internalListener.listener, internalListener.useCapture)
      const listener: IListener = this.#privateGetListener(internalListener)
      delete this.#listeners[strId]
      return listener
    }
    return null
  }

  // noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
  removeEventListeners(ids: Array<string | number>): Array<IListener | null> {
    const returnListeners: Array<IListener | null> = []
    ids.forEach((id: string | number) => {
      const returnListener: IListener | null = this.removeEventListener(id)
      returnListeners.push(returnListener)
    })
    return returnListeners
  }

  // removes all event listeners and resets idx
  removeAllEventListeners(): Array<IListener | null> {
    const ids: Array<string | number> = this.ids()
    const returnListeners: Array<IListener | null> = this.removeEventListeners(ids)
    this.#idx = 1
    return returnListeners
  }

  // same as removeAllEventListeners but no return value
  destroy(): void {
    this.removeAllEventListeners()
  }

  // returns ids of events listeners
  ids(): Array<string | number> {
    const ids: string[] = Object.keys(this.#listeners)
    return ids.map(id => this.#privateExternalId(id))
  }

  // returns number of events listeners
  length(): number {
    return Object.keys(this.#listeners).length
  }

  #privateAddEventListener(element: HTMLElement, id: string, type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture: boolean): string | number {
    if (this.#listeners[id]) throw Error(`A listener with id ${id} already exists`)
    element.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)
    this.#listeners[id] = { id, element, type, listener, useCapture }
    return this.#privateExternalId(id)
  }

  #privateGetListener(listener: IInternalListener): IListener {
    return {
      ...listener,
      id: this.#privateExternalId(listener.id)
    }
  }

  #privateExternalId(id: string): string | number {
    const idIsInteger = /^\d+$/.test(id)
    if (idIsInteger) return parseInt(id, 10)
    return id
  }
}

export const listeners: Listeners = new Listeners()
```

And TypeScript usage:

```
import { listeners, IListener } from './your-path/listeners'

// Add and remove listener
const listenerId: number = listeners.addEventListener(mainVideo, 'timeupdate', (evt: Event) => console.log('hi', evt))
listeners.removeEventListener(listenerId)

// Add and remove listener by custom ID
listeners.addEventListenerById(mainVideo, 'custom-id', 'timeupdate', (evt: Event) => console.log('hello', evt))
listeners.removeEventListener('custom-id')

// Log id of all active listeners
console.log(listeners.ids())

// Log active listeners count
console.log(listeners.length())

// Get details of removed listener
listeners.addEventListenerById(mainVideo, 'fred', 'timeupdate', (evt: Event) => console.log('bye', evt))
const removedListener: IListener | null = listeners.removeEventListener('fred')
console.log('removed listener was', removedListener)

// clean up
const removedListeners: Array<IListener | null> = listeners.removeAllEventListeners()
console.log('removed listeners were', removedListeners)

// simple quick clean up
listeners.destroy()
```

Advanced TypeScript usage for adding / removing multiple listeners in one call:

```
// Add multiple event listeners
const listenerIds: number[] = listeners.addEventListeners(this.video, ['timeupdate', 'seeking', 'pause', 'play', 'playing'], (evt: Event) => {
  const target = evt.target as HTMLVideoElement
  this.currentTime = target.currentTime
})
console.log(listenerIds)

// Add multiple event listeners with custom IDs
listeners.addEventListenersByIds(this.video, ['id-one', 'id-two', 'id-three'], ['timeupdate', 'seeking', 'pause'], (evt: Event) => {
  console.log(evt)
})

// Remove multiple event listeners
const removedListeners: Array<IListener | null> = listeners.removeEventListeners([...listenerIds, 'id-two'])
console.log(removedListeners)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you dont have to support IE, you can use the once option

```
[Element].addEventListener('click', () => {...}, {
  capture: false,
  once: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, since many people seem to look for this post:

You can directly use an abort controller to abort the event handler on an anonymous function, instead of going over removeEventListener()

In your example:

```
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal;

function doSomethingWith(param) {
    document.body.addEventListener(
        'scroll',
        function()
        {
            document.write(param);
        },
        {signal}
    ); // An event that I want to remove later }

setTimeout(
    function()
    {
        controller.abort();
    },
    3000 );
doSomethingWith('Test. ');
```