# Timeindex on *.mov/*.avi file

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, video-player

I have a Problem with *.mov/*.avi files.

I have a script where the movie is embedded and I have JavaScript shortcuts to start/stop the film.

Now I want that my members kan make annotations to the filmsequences, like the one on YouTube where you can mark a specific time in the movie.

Right now I embed the Movie like this:

```
<object data= "demo.mov" type= "video/quicktime" width= "400" height= "600" name="movie" id="film">
<param name=autostart value=no />Alternative Text</object>
```

And I have shortcuts for the JavaScript functions like this:

```
document.getElementById(container).Play();
document.getElementById(container).Stop();
```

So how can I get the Time-Index? - Or is there another way (like an HTML5 Player) so I can get the Timeindex for my Comments?

Video JavaScript Code:

```
<video id="example_video_1" data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }'>
 <source src="demo.mov" type='video/quicktime' />
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
  myPlayer.currentTime(10);
  //myPlayer.play();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try [videojs](http://videojs.com)

Comment: I would love to use videojs - but as I said I need to support *.mov and Video.js can not support it. (at least not in a way I see)

Comment: MOV is not a good format for online videos. It requires iTunes / QuickTime to be installed in Windows OS. AVI is Windows OS only too (unless plugin is installed). Consider to use mp4 / webm / ogv format.

Comment: Problem is that all video material is in *.mov and a conversion would be problematic due to the value of data. - But I can have quicktime installed for all users that will comment. The avi files i can convert in a better format.

Comment: Use HTML5 `<video>` tag for MOV. I found a solution in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15636794/188331, requires modern browsers.

Comment: tried it - doesn't work for *.mov in safari or IE with quicktime

Comment: it seems there is no way to do this with *.mov - in other formats I have no problem...

Comment: what is the error shown? Plugin missing / cannot be loaded / anything else? What is your QuickTime codec ?

Comment: No errors at all. All functions come back with Value 0 under Safari. Chrome & FF can't play *.mov which is not a problem bc i can tell the ppl what to use.

My Video and JS Code:

`<video id="example_video_1" data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }'>
 <source src="demo.mov" type='video/quicktime' />
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
  myPlayer.currentTime(10);
  //myPlayer.play();
});
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good project for [WebChimera](http://www.webchimera.org/). It has a wide range of [video and audio format support](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.php?cat=input) (needs a plugin installed though).

Check out the [Wiki](http://wiki.webchimera.org/). If you are using WebChimera Player, to get the current time in milliseconds use `wjs("#webchimera").plugin.time`. If you want to learn [QT QML](http://qt-project.org/), you could even display the comments inside the video (like souncloud does).