# How to get current timestamp (not just in seconds) in HTML video

Tags: jquery, html

So I'm trying to get a current timestamp as in something with HH:MM:SS from an HTML5 video. I'm using a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380956/current-duration-time-of-html5-video/15636794#15636794):
**HTML**

```
<video
    id="video-active"
    class="video-active"
    width="640"
    height="390"
    controls="controls">
    <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="current">0:00</div>
<div id="duration">0:00</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#video-active").on(
    "timeupdate", 
    function(event){
    onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime, this.duration);
});

function onTrackedVideoFrame(currentTime, duration){
    $("#current").text(currentTime);
    $("#duration").text(duration);
}
```

My main problem is that the current and duration divs are just showing the 0:00 and nothing else. Is there something wrong with the code, or is there an easier way to get the timestamp of an HTML video?

Comment: Do you mean that it shows 0:00 and it does not increase? or you want to just change the format of that timestamp?

Comment: Are you sure it is not just a syntax error?  Your jquery snippet has unmatched braces/parens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, to solve the 0:00 problem, I would change TEXT to HTML

```
function onTrackedVideoFrame(currentTime, duration){
    $("#current").html(currentTime);
    $("#duration").html(duration);
}
```

then include MOMENT

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

convert seconds to milliseconds and create a MOMENT duration

```
    val = Number(duration) * 1000; //convert seconds to milliseconds
    var d = moment.duration(val);
var show_time = d.hours() + "hours" + d.minutes() + "minutes" + d.seconds() + "seconds";
```