# Video stutters every time it loops?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I've noticed that this is a common problem. I know there are similar question like mine but i haven't found an answer yet.
My problem is that i want to loop a video but every time it loops it stutters, freezes about half a second at the beginning of each loop. The video is short, about 6 seconds.
I wonder if this can be done with JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 video stutter on loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444784/html5-video-stutter-on-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. .mp4 was pausing on frame 1 for a few frames then the loop continued. I removed the audio track of the .mp4 during encoding. It worked seamlessly after that. Even though I had 'muted' set, it did not play smoothly until the audio track was removed altogether.