# How to get all videos duration before or without playing the video using jquery or javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have problem in my code to getting duration of all videos. error showing me undefined below my code please help me anyone for that.

```
    $("video").each(function(){
var duration = $(this).attr('duration');
alert(duration);
});
```

It's giving me undefined alert please tell me where I doing wrong I want all videos duration before playing video.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6380956/5051731) might help. Since we cannot see actual code, its hard to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `duration` property of HTML5 video,

MDN refernece https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration#Syntax

Comment: i don't know how to use this library please can use give me some demo code

Comment: no sir this is not solution i want all videos length not only one and without any click