# how to get the video played duration on video paused in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys I want to store the duration of the video played when user pauses the video. Which video is in the `<video src="">` tag

Comment: In the interest of content quality, Stack Overflow doesn't permit duplication of questions which have been asked/answered here previously. In the future, please use the search function or your preferred search engine to research your inquiry before posting here. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380956/current-duration-time-of-html5-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily get the duration of a video using js. Using the onpause event listener, we can then use `currentTime` to get the current time of the video. Here's an example of the usage:

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var time = document.getElementById("time");
video.addEventListener("pause", timev);

function timev() {
  var curtime = video.currentTime;
  time.innerHTML = curtime;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" controls></video><br>
<span id="time">0.0</span>
```

This just calls the function `timev()` on the video pause, and gets the time and updates the counter. In your question you also ask

> I want to store the duration of the video played when user pauses the video.

If you mean store it using javascript as a variable, the stored duration is the variable `var curtime`. If you want to save it and remember it even when the user reloads the site, you can use a database or localstorage.