# Does any knows how to control an Odysee embedded video?

Tags: javascript, media-player

Can I keep track of the time the Odysee's embedded video? I can embbed the video but I'd like to play where the user left off next time the page is opened. But I didn't tind any offical Odysee's API nor how I can do that usin g pure Javascript, due to cross-origin. I have no code to show because I didn't find any workaround. Are there any? any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily, instead of using the embed just put the link to the video in your own video tag

e.G

```
<video width="200" controls src="https://player.odycdn.....mp4#t=50">
```

then you can refer to all solutions available for doing this with the video tag (You will easily find how to get and set the position), look in my example i set the position to second 50 using Media fragments url

e.g

[current/duration time of html5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380956/current-duration-time-of-html5-video)

[Start HTML5 video at a particular position when loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981427/start-html5-video-at-a-particular-position-when-loading)

Comment: How can I do that with a Odysee's video? Couldn't find how so far

Comment: @Coder when on odysee, right click inside the video and klick "copy video adress" you can add this to the src attribute of the video tag

Comment: I've tried add to src attribute but I'm getting erro like this: "No video with supported format and MIME type found"

Comment: @Coder for me this is working perfect, i didnt post a real link here because it´s against SO Answer guidelines, but you can just checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1w263z47/

Comment: managed to do that! I did copy the download link intead of and it worked. Thanks. Let me see the JS code to keep track of the code then I'll return

Comment: didn't see that jsfiddle code before. I did find out at same time. Thank you again. I'm going to accept the answer.