# retrieve event object from javascript event and detach the event afterwards

Tags: javascript, event-handling

So I want to call a function and pass it parameters on a click event using vanilla javascript (which I've done) but I'm having a problem with detaching the event afterward. When the click event is fired I want to call a function and pass it parameters including the event object and then detach the event. I've tried a few things but the problem I'm running into is that the anonymous function can't be referenced after calling it so I can't pass it as a parameter to the event "unhandler". How can I capture the touch event while also passing parameters the the callback?

```
function bindClickExpandEvent(element, type, handler, obj) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, function (event) {
            handler(event, obj);
        }, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent('on' + type, function (event) {
            handler(event, obj);
        });
    }
}

function removeClickExpandEvent(elem, eventType, handler) {
    if (elem.removeEventListener)
        elem.removeEventListener(eventType, handler);
    if (elem.detachEvent)
        elem.detachEvent('on' + eventType, handler);
}
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery at all, you could use this http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This might help: [How to removeEventListener that is addEventListener with anonymous function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5660131/218196). The problem is that you can't unbind the event handler since you don't have a reference to the function you bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want to immediately detach the listener after the event has fired, you can do that directly from the handler where you *do* have a reference to it:

```
function bindClickExpandEventOnce(element, type, handler, obj) {
    function boundhandler(event) {
        removeClickExpandEvent(element, eventType, boundhandler);
        handler(event, obj);
    }
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(type, boundhandler, false);
    else
        element.attachEvent('on' + type, boundhandler);
}
```