# How can I create a wrapper function for addEventListener that works with removeEventListener?

Tags: javascript, callback, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to create a wrapper function for `addEventListener` that I can call as such:

```
aEvt('click', document, function (evt, target) {
  //Code here
});
```

I want to do this because it allows me to always have the event target available first from the start as a parameter.
I attempted such a function, but the problem is, in order to have it work with `removeEventListener` (or my analogous `rEvt` function), I have to return a callback from the `aEvt` function and pass that to `removeEventListener` as the callback.

The `aEvt` function I currently have is as follows:

```
function aEvt(evt, elem, fn) {
  'use strict';

  var callback = function (evt) {
    fn(evt, evt && evt.target ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement);
  };

  if (elem.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener(evt, callback);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
    elem.attachEvent('on' + evt, callback);
  } else {
    elem['on' + evt] = callback;
  }

  return callback;
}
```

Is there any way I can change the `aEvt` function so that I can send the target to the callback passed to the `aEvt` function (i.e., `fn`), but also have the callback I send to the `aEvt` function be the same callback that I send to the analogous `rEvt` function I want to write?
In other words, how should I change `aEvt` to make the following work?

```
var callbackFn = function (evt, target) { console.log(target); };
aEvt('click', document, callbackFn);
rEvt('click', document, callbackFn);
```

Comment: Have look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5660165/218196

Comment: Which is very similar to your current solution. The way you really want it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Felix Kling, thanks a lot for your answer in the SO post you linked to in the comments.

I took what you did and modified it slightly to 1) follow the JS code standards set at my organization, and 2) make it so that I could get the event target as a parameter in the handler callback.
Having the target available as a parameter makes handling events a lot easier in a majority of the use cases I have as well as greatly minimizes the amount of refactoring required.

Anyway, here's the final code (please note that the `each` function in `remove` executes a simple for loop, and `return false` in the function essentially breaks the loop):

```
var evts = (function () {
  'use strict';

  var listeners = [],
    add,
    remove;

  add = function (evt, elem, fn) {
    var callback = function (evt) {
      fn(evt, evt && evt.target ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement);
    };

    listeners.push({
      evt: evt,
      elem: elem,
      fn: fn,
      callback: callback,
      removed: false
    });

    if (elem.addEventListener) {
      elem.addEventListener(evt, callback);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
      elem.attachEvent('on' + evt, callback);
    } else {
      elem['on' + evt] = callback;
    }
  };

  remove = function (evt, elem, fn) {
    var callback;

    each(listeners, function (evtObj) {
      if (evtObj.evt === evt && evtObj.elem === elem && 
          evtObj.fn === fn && !evtObj.removed) {
        evtObj.removed = true;
        callback = evtObj.callback;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (elem.removeEventListener) {
      elem.removeEventListener(evt, callback);
    } else if (elem.detachEvent) {
      elem.detachEvent('on' + evt, callback);
    } else {
      elem['on' + evt] = null;
    }
  };

  return {
    add: add,
    remove: remove
  };
}());
```

And here's an example of using the methods:

```
var callback = function (evt, target) {
  console.log(target);
};
evts.add('click', document, callback);
evts.remove('click', document, callback);
```

Comment: Can you guys explain me the purpose of this. I have seen this sort of coding in many websites but I am not sure exactly why using aliases, wrappers and other helper functions. Also I interested on how "Having target available as a parameter makes handling events easier".

Comment: There are several advantages: 1) You can have one function that works in all browsers, regardless of whether the browser supports addEventListener, or attachEvent or whatever. 2) You can define your own interface. In this case, there's not a huge advantage, but typing evts.add is quicker and easier than addEventListener. In a more extreme case, I have created an alias for document.querySelectorAll called qSA. It does exactly the same thing, but is a lot quicker to type, which comes into advantage when you use the function a lot. It also makes your code shorter. 3) You can encapsulate the...

Comment: Functionality, which allows you to change the behavior behind the scenes without changing how the interface works. As an example, one thing I've added to this code is the ability to handle ghost clicks behind the scenes. For example, if you set up both a touchstart and click event handler for the same element, then when the touchstart event fires, you don't want the click event to also do something right after that. Because everything is encapsulated, I can change the code under the hood without having to change how I actually use evts.add, etc. This is a huge benefit. 4) Having target...

Comment: Readily available is also beneficial and is something that you don't readily have with addEventListener, etc. I commonly use event delegation, which typically means that I set a single event on the document object, and that way, I only need one event handler to detect when anything on the screen is clicked, etc. The target parameter tells me what was actually clicked on. This can also be a huge efficiency gain. If you want to know more, I would recommend doing a search for "JS event delegation", "JS revealing module pattern", etc. If you still have questions, please let me know. Thanks.