# Get a cookie when have click in to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cookies

I have this code that detects when a click inside the iframe.
Within the 'if', if the click, I create a cookie.
But the cookie is being created as I enter the page, not only when there is a click.

How can I make the cookie is created only when the click event happen?

```js
focus();
var listener = addEventListener('blur', function() {
 if(document.activeElement = document.getElementById('bloco')) {
  message.innerHTML = 'Creat a cookie visits';
       jQuery.cookie('visits', 1 , { expires: 7, path: '/' });
 }else {
  message.innerHTML = 'fail';
  
  }
  
  removeEventListener(listener);
});
```

```css
bloco {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<div id="message"></div>
<div id="bloco">
<iframe src="//example.com" width="300" height="400"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: `addEventListener` does not return anything, and as such that's not how `removeEventListener` works.

Comment: But without it I can not detect the click in the iframe :(

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660131/how-to-removeeventlistener-that-is-addeventlistener-with-anonymous-function for how to properly remove event listeners.

Comment: I have other script, but doesnt working ;(
http://jsfiddle.net/isaicsg/1r2jkv6t/