# stop function after time period

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-select

```
    var elelist = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < elelist.length; i++){
    elelist[i].addEventListener("focus", function(){
        this.blur();
    });
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/M30Ge1FgNo

The JS above looks for a focused input and then adds `.blur` to it. I'm trying to stop input from focusing first. But the above stops me using it altogether. Probably need to add a timeout to the `.blur` so it can be used after the list items have appeared. How do I add a timeout to remove .blur or refocus/remove .blur from the input.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660131/how-to-removeeventlistener-that-is-addeventlistener-with-anonymous-function

Comment: How about `for(var i = 0; i < elelist.length; i++){
    elelist[i].setAttribute("readonly","readonly");
}`