# RemoveEventListener not working when queryselectorall is used to access an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I'm making tic tac toe and all the 9 squares in the game have the same class 'box'.

```
const box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

box.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    insertMark(element);
  });
});

function insertMark(event) {
  if (player === 1) {
    event.innerHTML = "X";
    player = 2;
  } else if (player === 2) {
    event.innerHTML = "O";
    player = 1;
  }
  event.classList.add("boxInsert");
  event.removeEventListener("click", insertMark);
}
```

The eventListener works fine to insert a mark on the box, but I can't seem to remove the eventListener. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are removing the `insertMark` function from the element. That's wrong, because you have to remove the `() => { insertMark(element); }` function. Give it a name and remove that function.

Comment: `insertMark` is not the attached listener, an anonymous function is. You've to attach the listener like `element.addEventListener('click', insertMark);`. To get the element inside the event handler, use `event.target`. Take a look at how [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) works, you can reduce your code a bit.

Comment: you have to put the addeventlistener in a function, and remove it. check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to removeEventListener that is addEventListener with anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660131/how-to-removeeventlistener-that-is-addeventlistener-with-anonymous-function)