# Remove event listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, listener, event-listener

I add an event listener to an element:

```
/* sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers */
function AttachEvent(element, type, handler){
    if (element.addEventListener){
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    }else{
        element.attachEvent("on"+type, handler);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var els = getElementsByClassName('name', 'img');
    var elsnum = els.length;
    if(elsnum) //found
    {
        var i = 0;
        for(i=0; i < elsnum; i++)
        {
            var the_els = els[i];
            AttachEvent(the_els, "click", myfunction); 
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Later in `myfunction`, I want to remove the handler again, to prevent duplicate clicks:

```
function myfunction(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;  

    //more code
    //...

    //remove click handler
    target.removeEventListener('click', e, false);

    //more code
    //...
}
```

The event listener is not being removed, though. When I click on one of the elements, the code of `myfunction` is executed again. How can I remove the event listener to prevent the clicked element from being clicked again?

PS: I do not use jQuery.

Comment: If you want an easier implementation, read my answer way down on the bottom. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you're almost there, but you have to pass the *listener* to `removeEventListener`, not the event itself. So try:

```
target.removeEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forgot to handle IE with `element.detachEvent`. If in doubt, take a look a the quirksmode link @John posted, it's an excellent article on this topic.

Answer (score 7):

Use `element.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)`
Remember to use that on the same element, and give it the exact same parameters as you did for adding.

One excellent way to code this would be to make a function that stores the listener details in  a variable, mimicking how `setTimeout()` works for instance, and adding that to the element prototype. Here's an example function.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.eventListener=
function(type, func, capture){
   if(typeof arguments[0]=="object"&&(!arguments[0].nodeType)){
      return this.removeEventListener.apply(this,arguments[0]);
   }
   this.addEventListener(type, func, capture);
   return arguments;
}
```

That will add a method to all HTML nodes that already can accept event listners, and allow you to do this.

```
var a=element.eventListener('click', myFunction, false); //to add
element.eventListener(a); //to remove
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

To remove an event handler, use the `removeEventListener()` method.

Also see http://help.dottoro.com/ljahxbsx.php

`object.removeEventListener (eventName, listener, useCapture);`

`listener` - Required. Reference to the event handler function to remove. You need to pass what listener you want to remove.