# Best way to run mousemove only on mousedown with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, mousemove, mousedown

I do not want any unnecessary loops occurring for `mousemove` event. So I became interested, in terms of performance/best practice what would be the best way to run `mousemove` only while `mousedown == true`? Currently I'm using:

```
var pressedMouse = false;

myObject.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){

    mouseDownFunction(e); 
    pressedMouse = true;

    myObject.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if(pressedMouse == true){
            mouseMoveFunction(e);
        }
     }
});

myObject.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
    pressedMouse = false;
});
```

`mouseMoveFunction()` isn't being called because of the `pressedMouse` variable. Can `onmousemove` event be prevented from firing if `mousedown` not in use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can prevent the onMouseMove-Function to be called, by removing it from the listener:

```
myObject.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    mouseDownFunction(e); 

    myObject.onmousemove = function(e) {
        mouseMoveFunction(e);
     }
});

myObject.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
    myObject.onmousemove = null
});
```

Comment: But what if there was an unknown number of mousemove events associated to myObject, and you wanted to remove only the one you had set?

Comment: @wordbug do you mean by using `addEventListener` ?

Comment: Yes. It'd be consistent with your other uses (mousedown and mouseup), and it wouldn't interfere with other code that might coexist with this snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're going to be adding an event handler and then removing it, potentially over and over, define the mouseMove function first ready to accept an event object:

```
function mouseMoveFunction(e) {
//stuff
}
```

Now you can merely add a reference to that function rather than creating a new anonymous function that calls it whenever mousedown activates.  Plus, since we have that reference, we might as well use the standard add/remove-EventListener methods.

```
myObject.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    mouseDownFunction(e); 
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveFunction);
});

myObject.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
    this.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveFunction);
});
```

Comment: This fails for me because of reasons outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10444156/2734863

Answer (score 0):

In event object there is a property called 'which' what indicates which button is pressed during mouse move. Use this one to determine whether do some operation during mousemove or not.

Comment: But can I prevent `mousemove` from even firing without `mousedown` event?

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){


    myObject.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if(pressedMouse == true){
            mouseMoveFunction(e);
        }
     }
});
```

What you are doing in the above is everytime the browser detects a mousedown event you are adding an event listener for mouse move.

This will can crippple your performance..let's say you have 1000 mouse down then then browser will add a mousemove event 1,000 times

Create a separate event listener for mousemove (once)