# remove event listener in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function like so:

```
mouseClickNav() {

    document.getElementById('mouseClickNav').style.width = '319px';
    let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.canvasTest.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
        this.mouseClickX = mouseX;
        this.mouseClickY = mouseY;
    });
```

Which works fine, and adds the event listener. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to remove it after im done with it. The next function is where i want to remove the listener:

```
closeMouseClickNav() {
    document.getElementById('mouseClickNav').style.width = '0';
    let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.canvasTest.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('click', () => { });
 }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I declared the listener and added it, when i remove it doesnt it have to be the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript removeEventListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working)

Comment: except im not using vanilla js, im using typescript. perhaps im just not understanding how to use an event listener. should i make the above a function, and then add that function to the event listener?

Comment: Typescript doesn't make any difference. You're adding one function as an event listener and then try to remove a completely different function which will obviously not work.

Comment: So how can i access the same function in different functions? IE function 1 has a function called handler inside it, then calls an add event listener. function 2 then needs to somehow get that function, and remove the event listener?

Comment: Yes. The duplicate shows how to do it.