# how to remove listener by using classes

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I'm using StimulusJS for my js and I would like to be able to remove a listener when a user go to a new page.

So far I have created what it seems good for me

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"


export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.addListenerCloseModal()
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.removeListenerCloseModal()
  }

  addListenerCloseModal() {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.closeModal)
  }

  removeListenerCloseModal() {
    window.removeEventListener('click', this.closeModal, true)
  }

  closeModal(event) {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem is the listener is still there. I have read that comment about bind and this [Javascript removeEventListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working#comment73217796_10444156) but I don't really understand it . It seems like I should have a global variable which is binding my `this.closeModal` but how can I have a global variable in my class ?

Comment: Possibly it's the spelling error in `disconnect`? You have `disconnet`

Comment: Ah yes thank you, I misspelled it but even with the correct writing it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the case of *anonymous functions*. You're asking the browser to remove the event listener defined as *capturing listener* since your `removeEventListener` call has third `true` parameter. The browser can't find it because the event was added as *non-capturing* with `false` as default third parameter.

So in simple words adding and removing the same event should match the *capturing* state. See [Matching event listeners for removal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#Syntax)