# Removing beforeunload confirmation popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Is there any way from preventing this popup modal from occurring (in Firefox in this case, but I'd like to accommodate this change for all browsers)?

I am working specifically in React, but a vanillaJS implementation would work as well!

[image]

I already tried to remove the `returnValue` property of the event as discussed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload
in one of my components like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (ev) => {
    delete e['returnValue'];
  });
}, []);
```

but I am still seeing the popup. In fact, when I `console.log` the `ev` object, the `returnValue` property still exists, but is just an empty string. When I try setting the `returnValue` property to something like `null`/`false`, it just sets the `returnValue` to the string version of those values (`"null"`/`"false"`).

Any help or insight into what steps or direction I should take next would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: By default this message should show up, if it does, it's certainly because somewhere in your code something tells it to. So the best would be to find this somewhere and change it so that it doesn't anymore. If you can't do that, an other solution would be to attach an other event handler **before** that one is attached, and to call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` from there. However, you MUST attach this event before the other one.

Comment: I was accidentally calling `ev.preventDefault()` in my client websocket which would by default show the popup modal in Firefox.

Comment: Great you found it. (to be clear my previous comment should have read "
By default this message should **not** show up,").

Answer (score 0):

So is my understanding correct that you've added the eventListener on one component? And would like to remove it (for whatever reason) in another?

I had a very similar issue in a VueJS app, but I think the solution would work for any framework.

The first thing you have to understand is that, the second argument does mean something. Can you can't just use:

```
window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', (ev) => {
  // call back contents
});
```

Because the callback when you add and remove aren't the 'same'.

Kind of like this:

```
a = {}
b = {}
```

You would think `a === b`? Nope, not in Javascript.

Therefore, you would have to use something like this:

```
function showModal() {
  // shows the modal and stuff
}

document.addEventListner('beforeunload', showModal, true);

// some other place

document.removeEventListener('beforeunload', showModal, true);
```

Now you are 100% sure that the same function is being removed. Also read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working) answer. It helped me solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not trying to remove a custom modal, but the default 'are you sure you want to leave' modal given by the browser. This modal usually pops up when you have unsaved changes in a form/textfield. I thought that I was adding an event listener for the `beforeunload` event which is when this modal pops up and then setting the right properties to undefined (or deleting them) to prevent the modal from actually popping up.

Comment: React (w/ redux) with the antd component library. However, this seems to be browser specific because I seem to only get these popups frequently when using Firefox/Safari as opposed to Chrome.

Comment: Sorry misread, that is surprising that you are even seeing that modal without specifically adding the eventListener on mount. 

On a sidenote, you cannot change or modify the contents of that pop up

Comment: I saw that you can't modify the contents of that popup, but is it possible to disable it by default?

Comment: Well, I'm surprised that you even see that modal without explicitly adding an eventListener for it. If you hadn't it shouldn't appear, regardless of you having saved changes or not.

Comment: I just figured out the issue! When my websocket client instance closes, I called `ev.preventDefault()` which automatically causes this popup to occur in Firefox. Removing the preventDefault gets rid of this error :) 
Thanks for the help!