# removeEventListener isn't working despite function and target being the same than in the addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Considering the following code :

```
switch(checkState) {
    case 0: pixel.addEventListener('mouseover', addColor);
    console.log("test");
    break;

    case 1: pixel.removeEventListener('mouseover', addColor);
    console.log("test2");
    break;
}
```

The function containing this switch statement is called on other event, and should either add listeners if checkState === 0, or remove them if checkState === 1. But listeners aren't removed on checkState === 1, despite "test2" showing in the console.

I made sure that :

- addColor is a declared function (so both addEvent and removeEvent reference the same function) ;
- both handlers refer the same DOM elements ;
- Not using the .bind method.

I also dug into [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working) but unfortunately didn't find the solution.

Here is a [replit](https://replit.com/@hirono9730/ValidBoringRadius#script.js).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you explain what is meant to happen? Do you want to highlight a block when it's hovered over and when it's clicked?

Comment: @Andy It's supposed to set block background to black if the mouse is clicked and hovering the block.

Comment: Do you expect removal of the `addColor` function from the `mouseover` event to remove the background color? It won't.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles no I expect that when I release the button the listeners are removed, and so when I hover white blocks they don't turn to black - I expect black blocks to stay black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `addColor()` function declaration outside the `checkHover()` function:

```
function addColor ({target}) { target.style.backgroundColor = 'black'; }

function checkHover(pixel) {

  switch (checkState) {
    case 0: pixel.addEventListener('mouseover', addColor);
      console.log("test");
      break;

    case 1: pixel.removeEventListener('mouseover', addColor);
      console.log("test2");
      break;
  }

}
```

By declaring it inside the `checkHover()` function a new function is created, therefore not referencing the old function that was previously added.

---

Does not remove previously added handler:

```js
const pixel = document.querySelector('div');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
let checkState = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', function ({target}) {
    checkState = 1;
  checkHover(pixel);
})
checkHover(pixel);

function checkHover(pixel) {

  // NOT HERE
  let addColor = function() { pixel.style.backgroundColor = 'black'; }

  switch (checkState) {
    case 0: pixel.addEventListener('mouseover', addColor);
      console.log("test");
      break;

    case 1: pixel.removeEventListener('mouseover', addColor);
      console.log("test2");
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<button>click first — does not remove listener</button>
<div>hey</div>
```

Removes previously added handler:

```js
const pixel = document.querySelector('div');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
let checkState = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', function ({target}) {
    checkState = 1;
  checkHover(pixel);
})
checkHover(pixel);

// HERE
function addColor ({target}) { target.style.backgroundColor = 'black'; }

function checkHover(pixel) {


  switch (checkState) {
    case 0: pixel.addEventListener('mouseover', addColor);
      console.log("test");
      break;

    case 1: pixel.removeEventListener('mouseover', addColor);
      console.log("test2");
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<button>click first — does remove listener</button>
<div>hey</div>
```

Comment: Problem is that if I do this, `pixel` in `pixel.style.backgroundColor` becomes undefined. I tried using a declared function taking pixel as a parameter, but I can't pass that parameter  with addEventListener.

Comment: I managed to solve this by rewriting addColor as `let addColor = function(e) {this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';}`

Thank you for your insight, I've been busting my ass on this for the past 5 hours and if it wasn't for you I think I'd have been there until the end of time.

Comment: Good, and I updated my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative approach which doesn't require you to remove listeners.

For ease I've used [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) here. All the boxes in the grid are initialised with a `white` class. Attach *three* listener to the grid element ([event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)) - `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `mousemove`.

If the `mousedown` event is fired a `down` flag is set `true`. If `mouseup` is fired `down` is set to `false`. If `mousemove` is fired *and* `down` is `true` it checks that the box is white, and then sets the new style.

Everything else is handled by the CSS.

```js
// Initialise the grid element
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

// Initialise the listeners on the grid element
['mousedown', 'mouseup', 'mousemove'].forEach(e => {
  grid.addEventListener(e, handleMouse);
});

// Create a grid of boxes initialising them with a white class
function createGrid(gridNumber) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= gridNumber * gridNumber; i++) {
    const box = document.createElement('div');
    box.classList.add('box', 'white');
    grid.appendChild(box);
  }
}

createGrid(16);

// Initialise the `down` flag
let down = false;

// Check for the events, setting the `down` flag
// for `mousedown/up`, and if the `mousemove` event
// fires and `down` is `true` then set the box style
function handleMouse(e) {
  if (e.type === 'mousedown') down = true;
  if (e.type === 'mouseup') down = false;
  if (e.type === 'mousemove' && down) {
    if (e.target.matches('.box.white')) {
      e.target.classList.remove('white');
      e.target.classList.add('black');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin: 0 0 2em 0; }
.grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr); border: 1px solid lightgray; gap: 0;}
.box { height: 20px; width: 20px; }
.box:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.black { background-color: black; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it requires to fully click a pixel to color it. You don't have the effect that while mouse is down it, hovering the gird let a black trail, but it stops when you release the click. I've since then worked an other solution that doesn't involve removing the listener, even if bloodyKnuckles solution did work.

Comment: @NonoNunu - sorry, I misread the question. I've updated my answer which maybe more in line with what you wanted, and is probably similar to the answer you arrived at.

Comment: yep, I did something along those lines. I declared a control variable similar to your `down`, added window.onmouseup and window.onmousedown to control it, and a conditional statement in my event listeners to paint only if mouse is down. Also I didn't know you could add several listeners at once with that syntax so that's nice !