# How can i stop or remove the mouseover event in etch-a-sketch in JavaScript. (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mouseover, mouseup, removeeventlistener

I'm currently doing the etch-a-sketch project of The Odin Project curriculum.

I have this event that when i click and mouseover the div, changue the background color, but I don't know how to remove this event when i release the click.

I tried using removeEventListener, tried using mouseup event but I can't figure out how to make this work.

I want to click and mouseover to draw and when i release the click stop the mouseover and stop to draw.

Another thing is that when I click in some div, this div do not change the background color immediately unless I move to another one on his side, then this other change the color.

Here is my code.

The HTML <body> only have a <div> with "grid-container" Id

JavaScript:

```
const divCont = document.getElementById("grid-container");

for (i = 1; i<=16; i++) {
    let divCol = document.createElement('div')
    divCol.classList.add("grid");
    for ( j = 1; j<=16; j++){
        let divRow = document.createElement('div');
        divRow.classList.add("secGrid");
        divCol.appendChild(divRow);
    }
    divCont.appendChild(divCol);
}

const hoverDivs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.secGrid')];

function colorChange(){
    hoverDivs.forEach(hoverDiv => {
        hoverDiv.addEventListener('click', () => { 
            hoverDivs.forEach(hoverDiv => {
                hoverDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                    hoverDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black"
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

colorChange();
```

CSS:

```
* body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    max-width: fit-content;
    margin: auto;
}

#grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    max-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    background-color: black;
}

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.secGrid {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

Comment: [This came up yesterday - these answers may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74253563/removeeventlistener-isnt-working-despite-function-and-target-being-the-same-tha/74254385)

Comment: Thanks @Andy. I already found a solution. 

I let the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already have a solution.

I set a variable that says if it's `onmousedown` or not (`changeColor`). So if `changeColor` is true, `onmouseover` is active, if not, isn't active.

```
const divCont = document.getElementById("grid-container");

for (i = 1; i<=16; i++) {
    let divCol = document.createElement('div')
    divCol.classList.add("grid");
    for ( j = 1; j<=16; j++){
        let divRow = document.createElement('div');
        divRow.classList.add("secGrid");
        divCol.appendChild(divRow);
    }
    divCont.appendChild(divCol);
}

const hoverDivs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.secGrid')];


let changeColor = false;

hoverDivs.forEach(hoverDiv => {
 hoverDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    hoverDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black"
    changeColor=true;
 });
 
 hoverDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
   changeColor=false;
 });
 
 hoverDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  if(changeColor){
    hoverDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
});
});
```