# Can't remove events from Azure Maps in Angular

Tags: angular, azure-maps

I'm trying to implement Azure Maps and I'm running into an issue.
I'm creating and removing layers at run time, and every time I set a new layer I add the event 'mouseup' on that layer to be able to click on markers, like this:

```
map.events.add('mouseup', layer, this.onMarkerClick);
```

When I switch layers, I try to remove the events like this:

```
map.events.remove('mouseup', layer, this.onMarkerClick);
```

But when this line is called, nothing seems to happen and the event callback keeps being called when I click a marker.
This means that, after switching layers a few times, the onMarkerClick callback gets called multiple times per click.

I tried calling map.events.remove in multiple location in the code, before and after removing the layer itself. Saving the layer to a property and using that in the remove function. Saving the ID in a string property and using it the get the layer from the map and then using that in the remove function.
None seemed to work, no matter how I call map.events.remove, the event keeps getting triggered.

Does anyone know what to do?
I've tried looking for code examples of maps.events.remove being used for a situation similar to mine but I can't seem to find any...

Comment: I must add, the map.events.add line is called within an anonymous lambda, does this affect this at all?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with how the callback function is referenced. If the callback functions are like the following, it is difficult to remove the reference:

```js
function onMarkerClick(e) {
}
```

However, if you modify it to the following, it works better:

```js
var onMarkerClick = (e) => {
}
```

I've come across this in many different web apps in the past (even when not using Azure Maps), particularly those that use frameworks like React and Angular.

Comment: Here is a thread that shows a similar issue occurring in non-Azure Maps apps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working

Comment: Thanks for the information!
I've tried putting the functions inside of private properties and in public vars inside the class, but this doesn't seem to help.

I have an inkling that this might have something to do with how Dispatch function of the NgRX Store. Since the Add and Remove functions are being called within a Dispatch their context might have completely changed?

Also, when removing and adding a new layer (I used the same LayerID though...) the events still get called. So my current fix is to add a flag if the events are set, and just not setting them again.