# RemoveEventLisenter not working after clicking 'Add New Task' button

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

How to remove the event Listener from items (Task1, Task2) after clicking the 'Add new Task' button?

I want to remove hidingAndShowing function which is hiding nodeElements that are not the currentTarget because after adding a new Task (Add New Task Btn) the nodeList to which hidingAndShowing function is referring to has changed therefore all initial added EventListeners need to be removed and added again.
This is the code -> https://codepen.io/Tukoruzi/pen/QWJbyeX

In other words after 'Task N' has been added and opened I want it to close after either 'Task1' or 'Task2' has been clicked and opened.

```
const addNewTask = document.querySelector('.new-task-js');
addNewTask.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const accordion = document.querySelector('.accordion');
  accordion.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newTask);

  // remove existing EventListeners because nodeList has changed
  const acc = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item-trigger");
  // NOT WORKING!!
  nodeList.forEach(item => {
    item.removeEventListener("click", hidingAndShowing);
  });
 // Add hideShowTarget to newly added Task (by addAdjacentHTML);
  const mostRecentTask = accordion.lastChild.querySelector('.accordion-item-trigger');
 mostRecentTask.addEventListener('click', function(e) {                 hideShowTarget(e); 
  });
 // Handle New Node List anew
 const newNodeList = Array.from(acc);
 newNodeList.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  hidingAndShowing(item,newNodeList);
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Where is `hidingAndShowing` _added_? Do you expect `hidingAndShowing` and `function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); hidingAndShowing(item,newNodeList); }` to be the same function? Why?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you are saying. You mean that function(e) { e.stopPropagation() hidingAndShowing is an anonymous function.

Comment: Anonymity doesn’t matter; the _function references_ need to be identical.

Comment: Ok but check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working where the guy in OP is writting what would seem two identical function references

Comment: The question remains how to pass updated nodeList as a parameter inside addEventListener if I write function like this: item.addEventListener("click", hidingAndShowing); The only option remains to define nodeList CONST inside 'hidingAndShowing' function declaration so that on each evokation nodeList will be 'up to date'

Comment: Either way thanks for help

Comment: In this case, you can try using [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of adding several event listeners — it’s more maintainable and applies to dynamically added elements. See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [this Q&A](/a/34896387/4642212). Then you won’t need to worry about `removeEventListener`; simply use an `if` statement to control whether `hidingAndShowing` should be called or not.

Comment: eventListeners should be added with named function not anon function if you plan to use `removeEventListener()`.  Even if you did remove the eventListeners it wouldn't matter because the eventlisteners are added again when `newNodeList` is created. So everytime you add a new task, the older  `.accordion-item-trigger` gets an extra identical eventListener.

Comment: @zer00ne I modified my solution a little check out whether it looks better now -> https://codepen.io/Tukoruzi/pen/mdQJPqv

Comment: @PiotrDeja Now that you're using named event handlers your eventListeners should have no problem being removed. Unfortunately, at the very end you still add them back. Why would you want to remove the eventListeners anyway?