# Remove added event listener

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

I am adding some listener in my html page using the following javascript. But i need to remove the listener once that element is clicked. Any idea on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the JavaScript code for the listener,

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    var elem = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (prevElement!= null) {prevElement.classList.remove("className");}
    elem.classList.add("className");
    prevElement = elem;
},true);
```

Comment: If you did [some searching](http://google.com/?q=javascript+removeeventlistener) you get enough information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener

Comment: Here is a similar question with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a named function. You can then just use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener) to remove it:

```
function mouseMoveCallback(e) {
    // Put your code here...
}

function clickCallback(e) {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveCallback, true);
    document.removeEventListener('click', clickCallback, true);
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveCallback, true);
document.addEventListener('click', clickCallback, true);
```

Comment: He wants to remove it once a click has happened, otherwise making a separate function declaration wouldn't be necessary