# Removing onclick from my images

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I have the following javascript code. Basically it's creating a online version of the card game 'memory' (ie. you have hidden images in a grid, you flip one and need to find it's matching image). Everything is working fine for me except for after my images have been matched. If they are matched, I want to remove the onclick event from the image, to prevent the user from clicking it again. However, everything I've looked up, and tried is not working for me.

Part of my requirement is that I "change the onclick event handlers for firstFlip and secondFlip to an anonymous function that does nothing but return the value false." Here is the snippet I'm using to remove the events (part of the checkTiles() function):

```
  firstFlip.onclick = function(){return false;};
  secondFlip.onclick = function(){return false;};
```

And here is the entire javascript code:

```
/*
  Filename: tiles.js


   Global Variables
   flipCount
      Used to track the number of tiles currently being turned over

   firstFlip
      Used to reference the first tile turned over

   secondFlip
      Used to reference the second tile turned over


   Functions

   addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap)
      Run the function fnName when the event evName occurs in object.

   randomSort(arr)
      Randomly sorts the contents of the arr array.

   setOpacity(object, value)
      Sets the opacity level of object to value

   setupTiles()
      Sets up the tiles for use in the Concentration game

   flipTile()
      Flips a tile showing the image associated with the tile

   checkTiles(tile1, tile2)
      Checks whether the tile1 image source is the same as the
      tile2 image source

   flipBack()
      Flips back flipped over tiles and resets the flipCount
      variable to 0.
*/

var flipCount = 0;
var firstFlip = new Image();
var secondFlip = new Image();

addEvent(window,"load", setupTiles, false);

function setupTiles() {
   var tiles = new Array();     // array of tile images
   for  (i = 0;i < document.images.length; i++) {  // go through all images
      image = document.images[i]; 
      if (image.className == "tile" && image.parentNode.tagName == "A") {  // must be of class tile and enclosed in <a></a>
         tiles.push(image);     // add tile to array
      }
   }

   var tileImages = new Array(tiles.length);     // array holding actual tile images
   for(j = 0; j < tileImages.length/2; j++) {
      var picture = new Image();
      picture.src = "tileImage" + j + ".jpg";
      tileImages[j] = picture;
   }
   for(n = tileImages.length/2; n < tileImages.length; n++) {
      picture = new Image();
      picture.src = "tileImage" + (n - tileImages.length/2) + ".jpg";
      tileImages[n] = picture;
   }

   randomSort(tileImages);    // randomly position the images in the array

   for(m = 0; m < tiles.length; m++) { 
      tiles[m].flipped = tileImages[m];      // custom property to reference flipped image
      addEvent(tiles[m], "click", flipTile, false);   // run flipTile whenever image is clicked
   }


   showAll = document.getElementById("showAll");
   showAll.onclick = function() {
      for(h = 0; h < tiles.length; h++) 
         tiles[h].src = tiles[h].flipped.src;
   };

   reload = document.getElementById("reload");
   reload.onclick = function() {
      location.reload();
   };
}

function flipTile() {
   if(flipCount == 0) {
      this.src = this.flipped.src;
      firstFlip = this;
      flipCount++;
   }
   else if(flipCount == 1) {
      this.src = this.flipped.src;
      secondFlip = this;
      flipCount++;
      checkTiles();
   }
}

function checkTiles() {
   if (firstFlip.src != secondFlip.src) {
      setTimeout(flipBack, 800);
   }
   else {
      flipCount = 0;
      setOpacity(firstFlip, 70);
      setOpacity(secondFlip, 70);
      firstFlip.onclick = function(){return false;};
      secondFlip.onclick = function(){return false;};
   }

}

function flipBack() {
   firstFlip.src = "tile.jpg";
   secondFlip.src = "tile.jpg";
   flipCount = 0;
}

function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
   if (object.attachEvent)
       object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
   else if (object.addEventListener)
       object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

function randomSort(arr) {

   arr.sort(function () {
      return 0.5 - Math.random();
   })

}

function setOpacity(object, value) {


   // Apply the opacity value for IE and non-IE browsers
   object.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + value + ")";
   object.style.opacity = value/100;

}
```

Comment: Might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can simply add a removeEvent method:

```
function removeEvent(object, evName, fnName) {
    if (object.detachEvent)
        object.detachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    else if (object.removeEventListener)
        object.removeEventListener(evName, fnName);
}
```

And then call this with the image Element and the `flipTile` function as arguments:

```
removeEvent(firstFlip, 'click', flipTile);
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work. I'm doing this for a project and its tell me to "change the onclick event handlers for firstFlip and secondFlip to an anonymous function that does nothing but return the value false."