# Multiple scroll event definition, and discriminatory event unbinding

Tags: javascript, scroll, jquery

I ask a specific question about jquery scroll events, but it seems like the answer could have implications to jquery events in general (which I am also interested in knowing).

Suppose that jquery plugin `A` (e.g., jquery.scrollspy.js) binds a scroll event to `$(window)`

Now say that some site imports plugin `A`, but it also has its own custom javascript file `B`, which binds another `.scroll()` event to `$(window)`.

Later on, javascript file `B` wants to unbind its own scroll event, and leave jquery plugin `A` intact. How is this done?

and...

Is this method universal to all jquery events?

Comment: For those interested in doing this without jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery recommends to use on and off instead of bind and unbind.

```
function scrollEvent()
{
}
$(window).on('scroll',scrollEvent);
$(window).off('scroll',scrollEvent);
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 6):

Best to use jQuery's .on() and .off() methods rather than .bind() and .unbind().

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

You can also namespace the event by adding a custom suffix to the event name. You can then access that particular event later (to unbind for example)...

```
$(window).on('scroll.myscroll', function () { 
    // do something on scroll event
});
```

an den...

```
$(window).off('scroll.myscroll'); // unbind my namespaced scroll event
```

See https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. Didn't do enough research before asking question:

```
var fileBScrollEvent = function() {
    // do something on scroll event
}


$(window).bind('scroll',fileBScrollEvent);
```

...later on in the code...

```
$(window).unbind('scroll',fileBScrollEvent);
```

Comment: Solution isn't wrong, but jQuery prefers you use on and off (since 1.7).