# Minesweeper Remove event listener in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've created this two event listening function for my Minesweeper game. When I lose the game, I want to remove the event listeners so that I can't click on the cells after losing. How can I do it?

Thanks

```
board.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    var  cellIndex = e.target.cellIndex;
    var rowIndexx = e.target.parentNode.rowIndex;            
    right_click(rowIndexx, cellIndex);
}

board.onclick = function(e) {
    var rowIndex = e.target.cellIndex;
    var cellIndex = e.target.parentNode.rowIndex;
    console.log("coluna: " + cellIndex + " linha: " + rowIndex);

    if (primeira_jogada == 0 ) { timer(); }

    if (isBomb(cellIndex, rowIndex) && firstmove == 0) {
        moveBomb(cellIndex, rowIndex);
        refresh();
    }

    if (isBomb && primeira_jogada !== 0) {
        lose();
        //event lister stops here
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Comment: the right answer is `board.onclick=null;` since you can't use `removeEventListener` without using `addEventListener`

Comment: Didn't work, EventListener still awake

Comment: actually, worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use addEventListener and removeEventListener (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)