# How to remove eventListener in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a Eventlistener, that can to change css position. Now i want to set up second function, which can remove previous Eventlistener . this is html code:

```
<style> 
div.container {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

div.box {
    width: 150px;
    border: 3px solid coral;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="box" id="box1">This is BOX1.</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">This is BOX2.</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<p>Two 150 pixels boxes inside a 300 pixels container. It should fit nicely, but because of the borders and padding, the two boxes take up more space than 150 pixels each. This "problem" can be solved by setting the boxSizing property to "border-box".</p>




<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

da this is Javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

    document.getElementById("box1").style.boxSizing = "border-box";
    document.getElementById("box2").style.boxSizing = "border-box";
}


</script>
```

Comment: When do you want to remove the event listener?

Comment: After user will execute myFunction(). Also after Box position will change on "border-box"

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to remove listeners is to bind it with **addEventListener**, and then remove it with **removeEventListener**.
Such as:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myButton");

function listener(e) {
  // do things on event
}

// adding the event
el.addEventListener("click", listener, true);

// removing the event
el.removeEventListener("click", listener, true);
```

Notice that both **addEventListener** and **removeEventListener** are REFERENCING the `listener` function. You need that reference to later remove the event listener, thats how the `removeEventListener` method works.

Full answer has been covered before:
[JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)