# Removing eventListeners after a resize

Tags: javascript

I need to remove my event listeners after I resize my browser. I tried something like this:

```
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      const bp = this.breakpointInit.getValue();

      if (bp === 'mobile') {
        this.toggleMobile();
      } else {
        this.toggleDesktop();
      }
    });
  }

  toggleMobile() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.elements, (el) => {
      const activeClass = `${el.classList[0]}--active`;

      el.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
        this.switchClass(e, el, activeClass);
      });

      el.removeEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
        this.switchClass(e, el, activeClass);
      });

      el.removeEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
        this.switchClass(e, el, activeClass);
      });
    });
  }

  toggleDesktop() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.elements, (el) => {
      const activeClass = `${el.classList[0]}--active`;

      el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        this.switchClass(e, el, activeClass);
      });

      el.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
        this.switchClass(e, el, activeClass);
      });

      el.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
        this.switchClass(e, el, activeClass);
      });

      el.removeEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
        this.switchClass(e, el, activeClass);
      });
    });
  }
```

The said functions are triggered when needed, but event listeners are carried over. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning anonymous functions, which can't really be removed.

Try something like this:

```
let me = this;

//this probably won't work exactly as-is, but you should get the idea
touchStartHandler(e) {
    me.switchClass(e, el, activeClass);
}

el.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStartHandler);

//...

el.removeEventListener('touchstart', touchStartHandler);
```

Having a *named* function allows you to add and remove things whenever you want, because you have a reference to the original handler function.

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener

Comment: It doesn't actually have to be named. For example an anonymous function could be placed in an array and referenced by `.addEventListener` and `.removeEventListener` from that reference. As long as you're adding and removing the exact same instance of the function it will be fine.

Comment: @JonathanGray can you explain a bit more about what you're saying, perhaps as an answer?

Comment: @ArthurKay Thanks for the info, but the scope is a problem here and I don't know how to overcome it. Isn't there anything else I can do?

Comment: @TomekBuszewskiI updated my example to help you understand the scoping. You just need to have references to anything scoped (`this`, `el`, `activeClass`, etc) outside of the named function but still accessible to it.

Comment: @ArthurKay `this` doesn't need to be re-scoped as it is defined by the way the function is called by the event handler. Also `el` references the element that the event is targeting, which would be `e.target` so that doesn't need to be re-scoped either.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you declare a function you are creating a completely new function instance. That's why you couldn't remove it from the event listeners. An instance of that function did not exist to begin with. As long as you reference the same declared instance of a function it will work. For example (using an array):

```
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      const bp = this.breakpointInit.getValue();

      if (bp === 'mobile') {
        this.toggleMobile();
      } else {
        this.toggleDesktop();
      }
    });
  }

  var handlers = [(e) => { // touchstart
        const activeClass = `${el.classList[0]}--active`;
        this.switchClass(e, e.target, activeClass);
      },(e) => { // click
        const activeClass = `${el.classList[0]}--active`;
        this.switchClass(e, e.target, activeClass);
      },(e) => { // mouseenter
        const activeClass = `${el.classList[0]}--active`;
        this.switchClass(e, e.target, activeClass);
      },(e) => { // mouseleave
        const activeClass = `${el.classList[0]}--active`;
        this.switchClass(e, e.target, activeClass);
      }];

  toggleMobile() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.elements, (el) => {
      el.addEventListener('touchstart', handlers[0]);
      el.removeEventListener('click', handlers[1]);
      el.removeEventListener('mouseenter', handlers[2]);
      el.removeEventListener('mouseleave', handlers[3]);
    });
  }

  toggleDesktop() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.elements, (el) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', handlers[1]);
      el.addEventListener('mouseenter', handlers[2]);
      el.addEventListener('mouseleave', handlers[3]);
      el.removeEventListener('touchstart', handlers[0]);
    });
  }
```

This uses an array to keep track of function instances. Notice they are all the same code but technically different instances. If they are all going to stay the same then you can actually get away with using only a single instance for all event listeners.

Comment: I just realized this code will not work as `el` is not in-scope anymore. I think instead of attaching event listeners per-element it should be done on the entire document. I will modify this code so that it should work the way it is.

Comment: I have made the modifications so that it should work as-is now.