# How can I remove Event Listeners in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, listener

I have this code:

```
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(callback){
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

    eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {//script});

});
```

I want to remove the second listener after it has fired (chronologically the first one fires first, then the second one fires when it gets a message).

I really don't understand the syntax of the .removeEventListener function and how to apply it on my example. I already read that it doesn't work with anonymous functions in the listeners so I had to declare the functions first, is that right?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but bear with me. Here's how you add an event listener:

```
el.addEventListener("event", function () {
  // code
});
```

The `removeEventListener`'s signature is almost same, but here's the catch: You'll need to pass a variable that refers to the function that you passed to the `addEventListener`. Passing an anonymous function doesn't help (As you'll have no way to refer to it later). So, in your case, you'd have to pass a named function instead:

```
function eventHandler (e) { /* handle e */ }
el.addEventListener("event", eventHandler);
```

To remove it, pass it to the `removeEventListener`:

```
el.removeEventListener("event", eventHandler);
```

The `el` is the element you're adding the listener to, the `event` can be an event, like `click` for instance, and the `eventHandler` refers to the function object.

Comment: Thank you for the first real answer that helps me. I will try to define the function first. Can you tell me, what "el" is in my example? Is it "window" ?

Comment: Yes, in your example, `el` refers to `window`.

Comment: Also, `attachEvent` is only for IE8 and older. So, unless you're supporting them, there's no reason to use it.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, consider accepting it :)

Comment: What do you mean by "accepting it". A mental state or a function here in stackoverflow? :D

Comment: :D Did that. Everything works except for the "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(Handler2);" then I get "Error in event handler for tabs.onUpdated: TypeError: The first argument is the receiver and must be an object". Can you tell me what is wrong with that? There is no problem adding the listener, the assigned function is called but when I add this remove command, I get this error.

Comment: Currently reading this but could not fix it yet : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events

Comment: That is weird. I'd suggest posting another question.

Comment: `TypeError` usually means that the argument is of a type different from what is expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
target.removeEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
```

**Reference :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

---

**EDIT :**

```
var handler;
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(callback)
{
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
    handler = function(e)
    {
        // Script
    };
    eventer(messageEvent, handler);
});

var cond = window.addEventListener;
window[cond ? 'removeEventListener' : 'detachEvent'](cond ? 'message' : 'onmessage', handler);
```

Comment: Bear in mind that you have to pass in the correct function reference as well

Comment: I already read this and I dont get what values I have to add for the "target" , "type" and "listener" parameters.

Comment: Sry, you can't remove anonymous function in event, you can test my other solution, i have edited my post. Have nice day.