# handling event listeners in different functions

Tags: javascript

Suppose there are two or more functions and they consist of different event listeners. Is there any way to turn off event listeners in all other functions when I call to the function in Javascript?

```
function one(){
  //functions and some event listeners
}

function two(){
 //functions and some event listeners
}
```

So for example when I call the function one I want to turn of the event listeners in function two. Also, consider the case that there are many inner functions associated with each function for the event listeners. So is there any better way? of course, I heard about `removeEventlisteners` but when the function inside the function comes they cause problems. How can I solve this in Javascript?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, there's a possibility to turn off a class of event listeners.

Comment: I am using it for canvas element in html.

Comment: @Ananthu this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener

Comment: @PraveenKumar this is not a duplicate question. Its different read the question properly and mark it as different

Comment: @Ananthu Reopened.