# Javascript event listener remove

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I remove the `eventlistener` when a page navigates to another page in a single page app?

I'm facing this issue when revisiting that page, not when `eventlistener` is called

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("message", listenMessage, false);
  // console.log("false");
} else {
  window.attachEvent("onmessage", listenMessage);
  //console.log("true");
}
var listenMessage = function(msg) {
/**/
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Comment: "_remove the `eventlistner` when a page navigates to another page_" You don't need to do anything, if you're closing the current document, all the listeners will be gone with that document. Or is this some kind of a single page app?

Comment: Yes its single page using angularjs

Comment: How can i close that document because im using angularjs single page app

Answer (score 1):

Use removeEventListener to remove event listeners.

```
window.removeEventListener("message", listenMessage, false);
```

And detachEvent in case attachEvent is getting executed

Answer (score 0):

```
window.removeEventListener("onmessage", listenMessage);
window.detachEvent("onmessage", listenerMessage); // For IE
```

For more information, read the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/detachEvent

Comment: Actually im facing listener class added no of times when the page revisiting , so I want remove the listener  when that page navigate to another page

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a Layout Page and ,your first page and other page should based on this Layout Page.
After that you can describe a global variable
Before navigation you should change this variable's value.
Check your variable's value and use that method:

```
document.getElementById("Your_Element_Id").removeEventListener("Your_Listener", your Function);
```

Comment: Im using iframe in parent page ,have one action button  when im  click on the button in that child page at that time send message using window.parent.postMessage(status, '*'); and in  parent page using addEventListener.to get message, but , im navigate to another page and again back revisting page two times listener message added.so how can i remove listener when click navigate to another page