# removing event listener after firing it up

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following HTML

```
    <button id="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="outside">
     <div id='inside" class="animated">
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I click the button I first show the `outside` and then animate the `inside`. That works just fine.

When I click again, I first animate back the `inside` and then hide the `outside`. To do so I add an event listener to the `inside` div, to listen for `animationend`. It works fine the first time. However, the second time I try to hide the `outside` the listener is fired up and it does not work properly. Now, I'm trying to remove the event listener right after it is fired up the first time but I cannot make it work.

Here my last attempt.

```
...
hideOutside: =>
  @inside.addEventListener 'animationend', @handler(event), no

handler: (e) =>
 @sheet.removeEventListener @animationEvent, @handler(event), no
 @outside.classList.remove('is-active')
```

I have [seen sample on SO similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener) and I don't understand what is wrong with mine.

Thanks (please do not remove this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
@inside.addEventListener 'animationend', @handler(event), no
# ---------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

doesn't do what you think it does. That's actually calling `@handler`, not passing a reference to it so it is the same as saying:

```
x = @handler(event)
@inside.addEventListener 'animationend', x, no
```

so `@handler(event)` is being called before `addEventListener`.

You want to work with the function *reference* so:

```
@inside.addEventListener 'animationend', @handler, no
```

and:

```
@sheet.removeEventListener @animationEvent, @handler, no
```