# Reference bound function inside itself in strict mode

Tags: javascript, bind

I need to have a bound event listener function to reference itself, but I don't see a way to access itself in strict mode (`arguments.callee` is not available).

See the following code snippet for an example:

```
function callback(boundParam, event) {
  // This does not work here as not 'callback' was added
  // to the event bus but 'boundCallback'
  eventBus.removeListener(callback);   
}

function foo () {
  const boundCallback = callback.bind({}, 7);
  eventButs.addListener(boundCallback);
}
```

What are my options?

This is **NOT** a duplicate of [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener) as I need to reference a bound function!

Comment: @mike not really. None of the top answers would work here

Comment: Not a duplicate - this is an eventing system rather than a simple event.

Comment: `bind` creates a copy of the function to bind, and the copy has its own reference. You need to keep track of the bound listeners, so that you can get a reference to the copy at the time you want to remove an event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe inline the handler so that you dont need to bind:

```
function foo () {
  function callback (){
    //...
    eventBus.removeListener(callback);
  }
  eventBus.addListener(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that returns a reference to the bound function when called. Let's call that function `getBoundCallback`. Then, append it to the argument list of the `bind()` call in order to receive the function in `callback`. You should then be able to call `getBoundCallback` and get back the actual bound function:

```
function callback(boundParam, getBoundCallback, event) {
    eventBus.removeListener(getBoundCallback());
}

function foo() {
    let boundCallback;
    const getBoundCallback = () => boundCallback;
    boundCallback = callback.bind({}, 7, getBoundCallback);
    eventButs.addListener(boundCallback);
}
```

---

Note how the declaration and initialisation of `boundCallback` are separated because of the reference to `getBoundCallback` being required for the statement initialising `boundCallback`.