# Building calculator - Not getting it to work

Tags: javascript, function

I'm building a calculator, and while it's starting to work, I'm kind of stuck. I've pasted the HTML and the JS down here.

I've been trying to figure out what went wrong, and I think it's because of the functions calling each other and not properly... "closing/ending".  I've been trying to see what went wrong with adding console.logs. I'll break it down here:

I press "on" and function `listenFirst` gets run.
`listenFirst` has an `eventListener` and waits for the user to click a number (`firstNumber`). As soon as a number is clicked, `waitforOperator` is run (which now has the `firstNumber`as an attribute. Now, 
`waitforOperator` waits for a click on the plus sign, and as soon as the user clicks on the plus sign, `listenSecond`gets run. Now this is where it 
goes wrong: as soon as I click the second number, `waitforOperator`gets run again and now `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` are the same.

To be clear: I just want this problem solved before I delve into the other operators, so please don't pay attention to the other operators like minus and multiplication.

A nudge in the right direction would be nice! Thanks in advance.

```js
let displayBox = document.getElementById("displayBox");
let pressButton = document.querySelectorAll(".column");
let turnOn = document.getElementById("turnOn");
let minus = document.getElementById("minus");
let plus = document.getElementById("plus");
let firstNumber = Number();
let secondNumber = Number();

turnOn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  displayBox.textContent = "CALCULATOR ON. GIVE FIRST NR.";
  console.log("launching function listenFirst");
  listenFirst();
});

let listenFirst = () => {
  console.log("launched listenFirst");
  for (var i = 0; i < pressButton.length; i++) {
    pressButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      firstNumber = displayBox.textContent = Number(this.id);
      waitForOperator(firstNumber);

    });
    
  }
  
};



let listenSecond = () => {
  console.log("launched listenSecond");
  console.log(`first number is still ${firstNumber}`)
  console.log(`waiting for you to press second number`)
  for (var i = 0; i < pressButton.length; i++) {
    pressButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      secondNumber = displayBox.textContent = Number(this.id);
      console.log(`After click on second number, first number is ${firstNumber} and second number is ${secondNumber}`)
    });
    
  }
  console.log(
    `Now first number is ${firstNumber} and second number is ${secondNumber}`
  );
};
let waitForOperator = () => {
    console.log("launched waitForOperator");
    console.log(`First number is ${firstNumber}`);
    console.log("Waiting for you to press plus");
    plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
      listenSecond(firstNumber);
    });
  };
let calculateSum = () => {
  console.log(`Second number is ${secondNumber}`);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css"
    />
    <script
      defer
      src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      
    <section class="section">
        
      <h1 class="title has-text-centered" id="titleText">Calculator.</h1>
      
      <div class="container">
          
        <div class="field">
          <a class="button is-fullwidth is-static" id="displayBox"></a><a class="button is-success" id="turnOn">ON</a>
        </div>
        <div class="calculator">
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="column" id="7">7</div>
            <div class="column" id="8">8</div>
            <div class="column" id="9">9</div>
            <div class="column" id="minus">-</div>
          </div>
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="column" id="4">4</div>
            <div class="column" id="5">5</div>
            <div class="column" id="6">6</div>
            <div id="plus">+</div>
          </div>
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="column" id="1">1</div>
            <div class="column" id="2">2</div>
            <div class="column" id="3">3</div>
            <div class="column" id="equals">=</div>
          </div>
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="column" id="0">0</div>
            <div class="column" id="dot">.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never remove the event listener you added to number number buttons in `listenFirst`. So when the user presses the buttons after `waitForOperator` both the code in `listenFirst` and `listenSecond` runs. `listenFirst` call `waitForOperator` again.

[JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener) Have a look at this answer for how to remove event listeners.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

Well, I'm having trouble implementing it. Should I implement it into the listenSecond function? Or not? Because the eventListener still needs to work for the listenSecond to work.

Comment: As far as I can tell you need to create a new function which handles the events rather than a anonymous function like you are at the moment. Then you can remove the event handler by looping through the buttons and removing events which call that function as shown in the top example in the stackoverflow post I linked.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim. It works! Back in business. :) Have a good day/evening. 

For future reference: it was indeed the creation of a new function that handles the events that got it working.