# How can I remove event listener with click on text?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

i used eventListener for add textDecoration, so how can i remove textDecoration with eventListener?
it's To-Do list, and i need remove Done task to not-done.

I just wrote this for make the task done:

```
pTag.addEventListener("click", taskDone);
function taskDone(){
  taskTag.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

and wrote this for remove "textDecoration", but doesn't work and didn't remove textDecoration:

```
    document.removeEventListener("click", remDone);
    function remDone(){
        taskTag.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
```

so please tell me what should I do and what is the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Comment: click in the same `pTag`?

Comment: yes, click in the same pTag. like To-Do list!

Answer (score 0):

For DOM objects there is also `removeEventListener` method, which will remove listener from object. In your case you can call it:

```
pTag.removeEventListener("click", taskDone);
```

Answer to actual problem: Adding a check in callback function would be sufficient.

```
function taskDone(){
  if (isLineThrough) {
       taskTag.style.textDecoration = "none";
       isLineThrough = false;
       return;
  }
  taskTag.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  isLineThrough = true;
}
```

Comment: actually i used this :
        document.removeEventListener("click", remDone);
        function remDone(){
            taskTag.style.textDecoration = "none";
        }

but it doesn't work. i need to remove textDecoration  style with click again on "tag"

Comment: Question then is formulated incorrectly. In this case you could add functionality to your `taskDone` method.