# removeeventlistner not working on button click

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById('divv').addEventListener("click",func)
  function func(a){
   alert("oooo");
  }
  function abc(){
   document.getElementById('divv').removeEventListener("click",function(){func()});
  }
```

```html
<div id="divv">This is vivek</div>
 <button onclick="abc()">Remove</button>
```

I have a button and I want to remove the onclick event on a div after I click on the button.

Comment: Yes, `removeEventListener` does not work like that. Attach a named function (either declared or assigned to a variable) as an event listener, and refer the same named function when removing the listener.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like that:

```
document.getElementById('divv').removeEventListener("click", func);
```

See the explanation about [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

```js
document.getElementById('divv').addEventListener("click", func)

function func(a) {
  alert("oooo");
}

function abc() {
  document.getElementById('divv').removeEventListener("click", func);
}
```

```html
<div id="divv">This is vivek</div>
<button onclick="abc()">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding and removing the same function, and that is why it doesn't work.

You are adding like this: `.addEventListener("click", func")`

And you are removing like this: `.removeEventListener("click", function(){func()})`

`func` and `function(){func()}` do not refer to the same function, even though they have the same result, when called.

You need to remove exactly the same way as you remove; otherwise removing won't "find" the original function you added:

```
function abc(){
    document.getElementById('divv').removeEventListener("click",func);
}
```