# Disable/enable a EventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable the event listener when an element is focused on and renable the event listener when it is focused out. How can I do this?

```
*//event listener execute function on paste*
document.addEventListener('paste', function (evt) {
  pasteClipboardURL(evt); 
});

*//on focus disable event listener paste event and function*
$('#input-url').on('focus', function (url) {
  *//disable document.addEventListener('paste', function (evt)*
});

$('#input-url').on('focusout', function (url) {
  *//enable document.addEventListener('paste', function (evt)*
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Comment: Why not just add the paste event listener to the element instead of document? Since you can't paste to something without focusing it first, problem solved...

Comment: @HereticMonkey He needs it to go the other way around - there is *one* input for which the paste event should not trigger `pasteClipboardURL`. Guess a `stopPropagation` would solve it too

Comment: @Certain Ah, that makes more sense ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than dynamically adding/removing listeners, I'd prefer to set a flag which gets toggled on focus or focusout, and check that flag in the main listener:

```
let focused = false;
$(document).on('paste', (e) => {
  if (!focused) pasteClipboardURL(e);
});
$('#input-url')
  .on('focus', () => focused = true)
  .on('focusout', () => focused = false);
```

```js
const pasteClipboardURL = () => console.log('pasteClipboardURL');
let focused = false;
$(document).on('paste', (e) => {
  if (!focused) pasteClipboardURL(e);
});
$('#input-url')
  .on('focus', () => focused = true)
  .on('focusout', () => focused = false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="some other input">
<input id="input-url" placeholder="input-url">
<input placeholder="some other input">
```

You can also listen for a `paste` event on the input and use `stopPropagation` on the event, so that the document listener doesn't see it:

```js
const pasteClipboardURL = () => console.log('pasteClipboardURL');
$(document).on('paste', pasteClipboardURL);
$('#input-url').on('paste', e => e.stopPropagation());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="some other input">
<input id="input-url" placeholder="input-url">
<input placeholder="some other input">
```