# how to disable a function

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function function1 () {
  document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    console.log("hello world");
})
}

function onload() {
function1();
}

function function2(){
 document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    console.log("hello");
})
}
```

```html
<body onload="onload()">
<button onclick="function2()">click</button>
</body>
```

This code will alert hello world when i press space key.

And when i execute the second function, i expect it to alert "hello" when i press space key

but it executes both function and alerts "hello world" and "hello" instead, so i was wondering how can i disable the function1() and only alert "hello" instead of executing the 2 functions when i execute the second function and press space key

Comment: If you use event listeners then you can add and remove them when you like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener

Comment: you have to add the 2nd keyup event targeting to the button instead.

Comment: `"message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'",` **Please fix your snippet.** We cannot help you with code that isn't even remotely syntactically correct.

Comment: Why are you adding event listeners when the button is clicked? Why are you uselessly wrapping `function1` in `onload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues with your code. Here we go:

1. Do not ever use inline event listeners in your HTML like `<button onclick="function2()">`. It is widely considered really bad practice and has security issues. Instead, work with the DOM API and use `addEventListener`.
2. Why would your button add an event listener when clicked, repeatedly if clicked multiple times?
3. Most events are propagated throughout the DOM (that is called [*event bubbling*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles)), and means that when an event occurs on an element, the event is next propagated to that elements' parent element, and so on, until the event finally reaches `html` (which is `document`). You can suppress that calling `event.stopPropagation()` on the event in the handler where you want to prevent bubbling.
4. Do not use `event.code` since it [ignores the keyboard layout of the user](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code). Instead, work with `event.key`. A good site for quick keyboard event information testing is https://keycode.info/.

Please educate yourself about DOM events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Events

```js
function f1(event) {
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    console.log("hello world");
  }
}

function f2(event) {
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("hello");
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', f1);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('keyup', f2);
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```