# How do I remove addEventListeners and requestAnimationFrames?

Tags: javascript, listener, addeventlistener, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I'm working in a project with a soft page transition and multiple modules. On every transition the removeEventListeners() function in each module is called.

How do I kill all performance-consuming processes? In this case the mousemove listener and the requestAnimationFrame.

I know I can remove the listener of the mousemove event by using a function instead of the arrow function in the addEventListener. But then how do I manipulate the xmouse and ymouse values?

```
export default class Cursor extends Core {
init() {
        let xmouse;
        let ymouse;
        const friction = 0.125;

        this.$el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            xmouse = e.clientX || e.pageX;
            ymouse = e.clientY || e.pageY;
        });


        let x = 0;
        let y = 0;
        let dx = 0;
        let dy = 0;

        const followMouse = function followMouse() {
            requestAnimationFrame(followMouse);

            if (!x || !y) {
                x = xmouse;
                y = ymouse;
            } else {
                dx = (xmouse - x) * friction;
                dy = (ymouse - y) * friction;
                if (Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy) < 0.1) {
                    x = xmouse;
                    y = ymouse;
                } else {
                    x += dx;
                    y += dy;
                }
            }

            cursor.style.left = `${x}px`;
            cursor.style.top = `${y}px`;
        };

        followMouse();
     }
}

removeEventListeners() {
   // Kill all performance-consuming processes of this module.

   // this.$el.removeEventListener('mousemove'); <- there's no function to be removed.
   // cancelAnimationFrame(followMouse); <- followMouse does not exist here
}
}
```

Comment: _"followMouse does not exist here"_ - well then move it to a different scope? Currently you have made it a local variable inside your `init` function.

Comment: you need to use a named function so you can remove it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener

Comment: So how do make a variable in this example that is accessible to other functions?

Answer (score 2):

To cancel mouseevent you should not use anonymous callbacks

```js
function handleMousemove(e){
   xmouse = e.clientX || e.pageX;
   ymouse = e.clientY || e.pageY;
}

this.$el.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMousemove)

//.. to cancel mousemove event
this.$el.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMousemove)
```

To cancel requestAnimationFrame You need to store `id`.

```js
// ...
const requestId = requestAnimationFrame(followMouse);

// to cancel `requestAnimationFrame`
cancelAnimationFrame(requestId)
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a scoping issue for sure. However, I don't get how I can call cancelAnimationFrame(followMouse) within RemoveEventListeners() function since the followMouse const is declared in a different function.

Comment: Store Id in global space (inside init will be good option if you declare `removeEventListeners` inside init) and use `var` or `let` to store `requestId`