# Removeing Event listener in a spesific div area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a api code below the problem I have; is I can start eventlistener but cant remove it so I wonder if I can remove all eventlistener in a div area to stop that event listener?

> api.scene.addEventListener(api.scene.EVENTTYPE.SUBSCENE_PUBLISHED,
> myFunctionpicbir) = WORK;
>
> api.scene.removeEventListener(api.scene.EVENTTYPE.SUBSCENE_PUBLISHED,
> myFunctionpicbir) = NOT WORK;

( so in spite of that code I want to remove all eventlistener in spesific div area)

```
 api.scene.addEventListener(api.scene.EVENTTYPE.SUBSCENE_PUBLISHED, myFunctionpicbir);
    
    function myFunctionpicbir() {
      alert("1")
      setTimeout(function() {
        html2canvas($('#sdv-container-sky')[0], {
          x: 500,
          y: 0,
          height: 600,
          width: 900
        }).then(function(canvas) {
          document.getElementById('kumas_cizim').appendChild(canvas);
          api.scene.removeEventListener(api.scene.EVENTTYPE.SUBSCENE_PUBLISHED, myFunctionpicbir);
          myFunctiona();
        }, 1500);
      })
```

also I asked a question about that api [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590618/removeeventlistener-for-an-api-doesnt-work-shapediver) :

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Comment: As I saw this stops spesific remove eventlistener.. like this.removeEventListener('click', myHandler);   and as I told that doesnt work for that API.. so I need to stop ALL event listeners so I hope API listener will also stop.