# How to stop EventListener when height reached?

Tags: javascript, html

Would you tell me how to stop EventListener when #gallery 's height reached by scrolling. I mean when its reached 200vh (or whatever the value is), the EventListener stop counting.

So the #gallery is in the middle of window (middle section of many section). There are other section above and below #gallery section. I just want to trigger when **user start scroll** from #gallery section, the rocks moving by scrolling and when **#gallery section end** or reached the height (200vh or whatever it is) it will stop the rocks from moving.

I almost get there to finish my parralax things.

Here's my codes

```
<style>
#gallery
{
height: 200vh
}
.rocks
{
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.rock-1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 100px;
}
.rock-2 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    left: 20%;
    top: 120px;
}
.rock-3 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 80px;
}
.rock-4 {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    top: 130px;
    left: 31%;
}
.rock-5 {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    top: 110px;
    left: 5%;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.rock-6 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 20%;
}
.rock-7 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    top: 35%;
    left: 120px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.rock-8 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 25%;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.rock-9 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 30%;
}
</style>
<section>
// this is another section
</section>

<section class="section-study-gallery" id="gallery"> // when user scroll from here, EventListener firing and the rocks moving by scrolling.
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="gallery-container">
                    <img class="rock-1 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/yIbmDYw.png" alt="rock"/>
                    <img class="rock-2 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/MZutMpv.png" alt="rock"/>
                    <img class="rock-3 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/AZumOFI.png" alt="rock"/>
                    <img class="rock-4 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/yIbmDYw.png" alt="rock"/>
                    <img class="rock-5 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/MZutMpv.png" alt="rock"/>
                    <img class="rock-6 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/MZutMpv.png" alt="rock"/>
                    <img class="rock-7 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/AZumOFI.png" alt="rock"/>
                    <img class="rock-8 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/yIbmDYw.png" alt="rock"/>
                    <img class="rock-9 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/yIbmDYw.png" alt="rock"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section> // When section end, EventListener should stop firing and the rocks stop moving.


<section>
// this is another section
</section>

<script>
    var scrollFunc = function(e){
    var containerTop = document.querySelector('#gallery').getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
    if (containerTop <= 0) {
        if (!scrollGallery) {
            $('.rock-1').css('top',(400-(containerTop*.8))+'px');
            $('.rock-2').css('top',(200-(containerTop*.6))+'px');
            $('.rock-3').css('top',(500-(containerTop*.4))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-4').css('top',(600-(containerTop*.5))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-5').css('top',(600-(containerTop*.7))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-6').css('top',(400-(containerTop*.7))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-7').css('top',(600-(containerTop*.5))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-8').css('top',(200-(containerTop*.2))+'px');
            $('.rock-9').css('top',(200-(containerTop*.4))+'px');
        }    
    }
    if (containerTop > 0) {
        scrollGallery = 0;
    } 
    if (window.scrolly > window.innerHeight * 2) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunc);
    }
};
window.addEventListener('scroll',scrollFunc);
</script>
```

I'm new in Javascript, so sorry if this stupid question bothering you.
I really appreciate it, thank you!

**Update**

I've updated my codes to "ControlAltDel" codes. But the rocks are still moving when #gallery section end. It's still moving till footer section. It's almost there I guess...

Comment: use removeEventListener

Comment: @ControlAltDel Hi, would you show me the codes from my codes above? :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Comment: @DonaldDuck So the codes should lookalike this?


else {
scrollGallery.removeEventListener('scroll',containerTop);
}

So sorry but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AditLin No, you need to name your function, and then pass the named function as a parameter to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` should be called on the same object with the same arguments.

Comment: you should explain more what you want exactly. what do you mean by `the rocks moving and when #gallery section end it will stop the rocks from moving.` how are they moving right now .the page just scrolls?

Comment: @UmairFarooq I've updated my question, do you get it sir? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have "unanonyminized" your function, but you could probably do it with window.removeEventListener('scroll', this) using your existing code

```
var scrollFunc = function(e){
    var containerTop = document.querySelector('#gallery').getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
    if (containerTop <= 0) {
        if (!scrollGallery) {
            $('.rock-1').css('top',(400-(containerTop*.8))+'px');
            $('.rock-2').css('top',(200-(containerTop*.6))+'px');
            $('.rock-3').css('top',(500-(containerTop*.4))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-4').css('top',(600-(containerTop*.5))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-5').css('top',(600-(containerTop*.7))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-6').css('top',(400-(containerTop*.7))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-7').css('top',(600-(containerTop*.5))+'px'); 
            $('.rock-8').css('top',(200-(containerTop*.2))+'px');
            $('.rock-9').css('top',(200-(containerTop*.4))+'px');
        }    
    }
    if (containerTop > 0) {
        scrollGallery = 0;
      // I think this is what you want, or?
    } 
    if (window.scrolly > window.innerHeight * 2) {
        // This is where you want this function to stop working, right?
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunc);
    }
};
window.addEventListener('scroll',scrollFunc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I think I forgot to add the CSS too.
I put #gallery with height: 200vh; With your codes, its stoped whenever I scroll it instantly. All I want is the scroll reached 200vh and then the AddEventListener stop adding the 'top'. Do you get it? :)

Comment: @AditLin Okay I've updated my answer. If I understand correctly (and maybe I don't) this should be what you want

Comment: When its reached the height (200vh), the listener is still counting :( I've updated my question too. Hope you got what I mean! :)

All I want is when its reached the height (bottom) of #gallery, its stop counting sir.

I think it's almost there. After implement your codes, the rocks are still moving. I want to stop the rocks from moving after 200vh reached when scroll :)

Comment: I've updated my question sir, hope you get it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Lets Hope This Makes Sense..

`let winScrl = gallery.scrollHeight - window.scrollY;` this gives us the position of scroll inside.meaning this will be equal to zero when top of my window touches the bottom of the div.

What we don't want
[image]

[image]

But Instead We Want to it be `0`when bottom of the window touches the bottom of the div.so i am subtracting `window.ScrollHeight` again from my scrollVariable.

`let chckScrl = winScrl - window.scrollY;`

```js
var scrollGallery;

let gallery = document.querySelector('#gallery');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(el) {
  var containerTop = document.querySelector('#gallery').getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let winScrl = gallery.scrollHeight - window.scrollY;
  /*console.log(winScrl)*/
  let chckScrl = winScrl - window.scrollY;
  /*console.log(chckScrl)*/
  if (chckScrl > 0) {
    if (!scrollGallery) {
      $('.rock-1').css('top', (300 - (containerTop * .8)) + 'px');
      $('.rock-2').css('top', (200 - (containerTop * .6)) + 'px');
      $('.rock-3').css('top', (400 - (containerTop * .4)) + 'px');
      $('.rock-4').css('top', (500 - (containerTop * .5)) + 'px');
      $('.rock-5').css('top', (500 - (containerTop * .7)) + 'px');
      $('.rock-6').css('top', (400 - (containerTop * .7)) + 'px');
      $('.rock-7').css('top', (500 - (containerTop * .5)) + 'px');
      $('.rock-8').css('top', (200 - (containerTop * .2)) + 'px');
      $('.rock-9').css('top', (200 - (containerTop * .4)) + 'px');
    }
  }
  if (chckScrl < 0) {
    scrollGallery = 1;
  } else {
    scrollGallery = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
#gallery {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.rocks {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.rock-1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 10%;
  top: 100px;
}

.rock-2 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 20%;
  top: 120px;
}

.rock-3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 10%;
  top: 80px;
}

.rock-4 {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  top: 130px;
  left: 31%;
}

.rock-5 {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  top: 110px;
  left: 5%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.rock-6 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  top: 70px;
  left: 20%;
}

.rock-7 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 35%;
  left: 120px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.rock-8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 25%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.rock-9 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  top: 70px;
  left: 30%;
}

#temp {
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  // this is another section
</section>

<section class="section-study-gallery" id="gallery"> // when user scroll from here, EventListener firing.
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="gallery-container">
          <img class="rock-1 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/yIbmDYw.png" alt="rock" />
          <img class="rock-2 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/MZutMpv.png" alt="rock" />
          <img class="rock-3 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/AZumOFI.png" alt="rock" />
          <img class="rock-4 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/yIbmDYw.png" alt="rock" />
          <img class="rock-5 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/MZutMpv.png" alt="rock" />
          <img class="rock-6 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/MZutMpv.png" alt="rock" />
          <img class="rock-7 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/AZumOFI.png" alt="rock" />
          <img class="rock-8 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/yIbmDYw.png" alt="rock" />
          <img class="rock-9 rocks" src="https://i.imgur.com/yIbmDYw.png" alt="rock" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section> // when section end, EventListener stop.
<section id="temp">
  // this is another section
</section>
```

Comment: @UmairFaroow Thanks for the effort and the complete answer Mr Umair. But when I implement it, the EventListener firing from the top of the window, not the top of the #gallery section. I think the trigger to stop is already correct, but the EventListener is still incorrect.

If you put #temp from your codes to above #gallery section. its started from the top of window :) All I want to firing the EventListener start from #gallery section and stop when the #gallery's section end. But thank you for the answer, really appreciate it!